# URL routing regex

Tags: php, regex, routes

I'm trying to create a snippet of regex that will match a URL route.

Basically, if I have this route `/users/:id` I want `/users/100` to match, but `/users/100/edit` not to match.

This is what I'm using now: `users/(.*)/` but because of the greedy match it's matching regardless of what's after the user ID. I need some way of "breaking" the match if there's an `/edit` or something else on the end of the route.

I've looked into the Regex NOT operator but with no luck.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just trying to collect digits?

You could use `users/(\d*)/`

And this one is how you would do it if you wanted to collect everything until a `/`, and it uses a NOT, `^/users/[^/]*$`

Comment: Had to modify it slightly for my use: `^/users/[^/]*/$` but this is exactly what I needed to know, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead:

`users/(.*)/(?!edit)`

This will always require a trailing slash however. Maybe a better solution would be:

`users/(\d+)(?!/edit)`

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404037/regex-negative-lookahead) for more information.