# PHP Regex that matches HTML-start tags but ignores HTML-end tags

Tags: php, regex, php-5.5

I have this code that matches all start- and end-tags for HTML:

```
preg_match_all("/(<[a-zA-Z\/][^>]*>)/imu", $sentance, $start_tag_list, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

But I want it to ignore tags that start with: `</`

Comment: Then remove `\/` from your character class ?

Comment: I feel stupid. Thanks, it works perfectly now.

Comment: See [negative lookahead](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3404037/731240).

Answer (score 1):

This is your current regex (on [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/LRFiP_grOrsXvtNk)):

[image: Regular expression visualization]

It will accept any HTML tag where the first character is a letter (`a-zA-Z`) or a slash (`/`) followed by anything but `>`.

If you simply remove the slash from the accepted first characters, you get this:

```
<[a-zA-Z][^>]*>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]