# Regex Rules for First and Second Character

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I need help on following regular expression rules of javascript and php.

**JS**

```
var charFilter = new RegExp("^[A|B].+[^0123456789]$");
```

**PHP**

```
if (!preg_match('/^[A|B].+[^0123456789]$/', $data_array['sample_textfield'])) {
```

This regular expression is about

First character must be start with A or B and last character must not include 0 to 9.

I have another validation about, character must be min 3 character and max 6 number.

New rule I want to add is, second character cannot be C, if first letter is A.

Which means

ADA (is valid)
ACA (is not valid)

So I changed the regex code like this

**JS**

```
var charFilter = new RegExp("^(A[^C])|(B).+[^0123456789]$");
```

**PHP**

```
if (!preg_match('/^(A[^C])|(B).+[^0123456789]$/', $data_array['sample_textfield'])) {
```

It is worked for first and second character. If i type

ACA (it says invalid) , But if i type
AD3 (it says valid), it doesn't check the last character anymore. Last character must not contain 0 to 9 number, but it's show as valid.

Can anyone help me to fix that regex code for me ? Thank you so much.

Comment: Note that `[A|B]` matches one of: `A`, `|` and `B`. The `|` does not mean OR inside a character class!

Answer (score 3):

Putting all of your requirements together, it seems that you want this pattern:

```
^(?=.{3,6}$)(?=A(?!C)|B).+\D$
```

That is:

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- We can assert that there are between 3 to 6 of "any" characters to end of the string `(?=.{3,6}$)`
- We can also assert that it starts with `A` not followed by `C`, or starts with `B` `(?=A(?!C)|B)`
- And the whole thing doesn't end with a digit `.+\D$`

This will match ([as seen on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/ae0vm5CIeA)):

```
= match =         = no match =
ADA               ACA
ABCD              AD3
ABCDE             ABCDEFG
ABCDEF
A123X
A   X
```

Note that spaces are allowed by `.+` and `\D`. If you insist on no spaces, you can use e.g. `(?=\S{3,6}$)` in the first part of the pattern.

`(?=…)` is *positive* lookahead; it asserts that a given pattern can be matched. `(?!…)` is *negative* lookahead; it asserts that a given pattern can *NOT* be matched.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

  - [Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), [Alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), [Dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

#### Related questions

- [How does the regular expression `(?<=#)[^#]+(?=#)` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092797/how-does-the-regular-expression-work/)

---

#### On alternation precedence

The problem with the original pattern is in misunderstanding the precedence of the alternation `|` specifier.

Consider the following pattern:

```
this|that-thing
```

This pattern consists of two alternates, one that matches `"this"`, and another that matches `"that-thing"`. Contrast this with the following pattern:

```
(this|that)-thing
```

Now this pattern matches `"this-thing"` or `"that-thing"`, thanks to the grouping `(…)`. Coincidentally it also creates a *capturing* group (which will capture either `"this"` or `"that"`). If you don't need the capturing feature, but you need the grouping aspect, use a non-capturing group ``(?:…)`.

Another example of where grouping is desired is with repetition: `ha{3}` matches `"haaa"`, but `(ha){3}` matches `"hahaha"`.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Brackets for Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your OR is against the wrong grouping. Try:

```
^((A[^C])|(B)).+[^0123456789]$
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the code, i think it's somehow wrong, because, if i type,

ACA (is invalid) and it's correct, but If i type
ABC (is still showing as invalid, actually it should show valid)

But if i type more than 3 characters, it's show valid.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

i think it should be like

```
/^(A[^C]|B.).*[^0-9]$/
```

try this test code

```
$test = "
    A
    B
    AB
    AC
    AAA
    ABA
    ACA
    AA9
    add more
";
$pat = '/^(A[^C]|B.).*[^0-9]$/';
foreach(preg_split('~\s+~', $test) as $p)
    printf("%5s : %s\n<br>", $p, preg_match($pat, $p) ? "ok" : "not ok");
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the code. I tried with that, whatever i type, it keep showing invalid.

Answer (score 0):

In jasonbars solution the reason it doesn't match ABC is because it requires A followed by not C, which is two characters, followed by one or more of any character followed by a non number. Thus if the string begins with an A the minimum length is 4. You can solve this by using a look ahead assertion.

**PHP**

```
$pattern = '#^(A(?=[^C])|B).+\D$#';
```

Comment: I think `(?!C)` is better than `(?=[^C])`.

Comment: Indeed, I thought that after I posted, but I couldn't be bother to edit it :).