# How to validate that a string is just arabic and numbers?

Tags: c#, .net

The company I work in decided to sell a product to an Arab company.

I need a way to be sure that a string is just arabic letters or numbers (with space ofc).

how to do that please?

I searched on google but it seems that the arabic language is not so popular

Comment: you could consult the unicode charts and make a method that validates a string against your desired range of arabic chars

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Wouldn't it be enough to just use `char.IsLetterOrDigit` etc.?

Comment: @WimOmbelets Okay that is a good idea,I will try it

Comment: There's also the [Microsoft Translator API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576287.aspx)

Comment: @Luaan I just need the string to be arabic and numbers and space, but in your case, i will have english chars which is not allowed in this case

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8

Comment: @mohsensolhnia that is a lot of pain, could you help me please with a simple start up so I can continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use this regexp expression for what you need:

`[\u0600-\u06ff]\?[ ]\?[0-9]\?`

The [\u0600-\u06ff] is for the arabic characters.

Example:

```
internal bool HasArabicCharacters(string text)
{

  Regex regex = new Regex(

    "[\u0600-\u06ff]\?[ ]\?[0-9]\?");

  return regex.IsMatch(text);
}
```

Comment: that seems a very good solution, but please what if the use enter the number first then the arabic letter then a space then an arabic then a number, your way won't work. I need exactly like you did but without specifying the order. did u get me plz?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3533526/1697811 check here. Hope it helps you.

Comment: I will try with your solution. +1

Comment: You can also try "[0-9]\?[\u0600-\u06ff]\?[ ]\?[0-9]\?" to allow numbers before characters.

Comment: Or just `"[\u0600-\06ff\\s0-9]*"`

Comment: @Luaan that doesn't include the space, does it?

Comment: @AgnieszkaPolec `\s` means "any whitespace character". You can use space instead if you really only want a simple space.

Comment: @Luaan when I tried your regular expression, I got this exception `parsing "[؀-` why please?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this in my opinion is by Regular Expression.

Regex is a very powerful tool for these kind of tasks.

for example, you can write the following expression to filter only Arabic letters (I've used that for Hebrew): \p{IsArabic}

There is a built-in support for Character Classes in Regex.

Please find attached a great link that helped me understand exactly what is possible and how:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx

In addition, a must have tool for any Regex developer that both helps you create expressions visually, and evaluate those expressions against data and review the results.
Expresso:
http://www.ultrapico.com/ExpressoDownload.htm

Hope this helps,
Ofir.

Comment: +1 didn't know about the named language blocks, really helpful

Comment: @DGibbs which blocks? where did he state that please?

Comment: @AgnieszkaPolec Don't be lazy. Read the link he provided.

Comment: @DGibbs you completely right. I am a little lazy tired today. I will read them