# PHP String present in any position

Tags: php, string

In PHP, Suppose in a string
$str = "How are you";

"are" can be detected by strpos("are",$str);

How to retrieve that "w r y" is present in $str?
("WheRe are You")

I have tried the above. Using wildcard characters like * did not give me desired results..

Comment: Do you just want to know whether the characters are present or not or whether they are present in the given sequence?

Comment: `if ((strpos('w', $string) !== false) && (strpos('r', $string) !== false) && (strpos('y', $string) !== false)) {....}` `strpos()` doesn't allow wildcard characters

Comment: I think you should try with regular expressions

Comment: However, [fnmatch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php) does accept wildcard characters: `if (fnmatch('*w*r*y*', $string)) {....}` It is case-sensitive, but `if (fnmatch('*[Ww]*[Rr]*[Yy]*', $string)) {....}` will work case-insensitive, as would `if (fnmatch('*w*r*y*', strtolower($string))) {....}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
if (preg_match('/w.*r.*y/i', $str)) {
    ...
}
```

This requires them to be in this specific order. If you want to match them in any order, it should be:

```
if (preg_match('/(?=.*w)(?=.*r)(?=.*y)/', $str)) {
```

see [match multiple words in any order with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309494/match-multiple-words-in-any-order-with-regex?lq=1)