# Having trouble while searching in mysql via REGEXP

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am implementing search in my project so I have to search data which will be in any order so I'm following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309494/match-multiple-words-in-any-order-with-regex). But my query was not working

my php query is

```
 $cat="(?=.*Women)(?=.*Rings)";
 $sql="select * from tbl_jewellery where categories RLike '$cat';";
```

when I change regex to `Women.*Ring|Ring.*Women`
It works fine but `(?=.*Women)(?=.*Rings)` approach is easy and can be used for multiple words just adding them.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not implement `(?` syntax in REGEXPs.  I think MariaDB 10.0.5 does.

For a significant subset of such queries, you could use a `FULLTEXT` index on that `categories` with this:

```
MATCH(categories)
    AGAINST('+women +rings' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

That says both "words" occur, without limitations on order or proximity.