# Matching multiple different tokens in a string in any order

Tags: regex

I need a way for matching a "format" string. It should have either one or two `%d` tokens, any only one `%s` token. Also preferably it wouldn't allow any other formatting tokens such as `%f` etc. I've come up with a few halfway-solutions of my own that do not manage to get the full job done:

```
.*?(\%d).*(\%(?=d|s)).*   //Doesn't fit requirements
.*?(\%d).*(\%d).*(\%s).*  //Doesn't allow for any ordering of the tokens
```

My thought is perhaps searching for the sole `%s` token and doing lookarounds, but I'm not entirely certain how to go about doing that (regex is not my strongest suit). This is intented for use an a Java library, and I'm open to non-regex solutions, however regex solutions need to match the entire string (and I'd prefer not doing two/three different regex searches on a format string).

It should match `%d:%d:%s` as well as `%d:%s` for example, but not `%d:%d:%d:%s` or `%f:%d:%s`. Essentially this would be the requirements of the string:

- One or two `%d` tokens
- One `%s` token

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex: I want this AND that AND that... in any order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533408/regex-i-want-this-and-that-and-that-in-any-order)

Comment: I updated my question a little @AvinashRaj

Comment: @Barmar the problem I'm seeing with those is I would want to match one *or* two of the `%d` tokens.

Comment: You can combine it with negative lookaround so it only matches the specified number.

Comment: Unfortunately my regex skills are subpar at best :( . If I was able to whip that up I wouldn't be here hours into working on this.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yup! That's the concept, it's going to be passed to `String#format`, so I just want everything to pass except extra formatting tokens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the below regex which uses lookarounds.

```
^(?!.*%[^sd])(?!.*%d.*%d.*%d)(?!.*%s.*%s)(?=.*%s)(?=.*%d).*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hW9fI7/2)

**Explanation:**

- `(?!.*%[^sd])` String won't contain formatting characters other than `%d` or `%s`
- `(?!.*%d.*%d.*%d)` String won't contain atleast three `%d` characters.
- `(?!.*%s.*%s)` String won't contain atleast two `%s` characters.
- `(?=.*%s)` String must contain a `%s` character.
- `(?=.*%d)` String must contain a `%d` character.
- Match the corresponding string only if all the above conditions are satisfied.

Comment: I added a `(?=.*%d)` as well to at least require a single `%d`, but this worked, thanks!