# How to find group of words that is in random order(only the group of words no other words)?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have done some regex for 3 hours trying  to figure this out.

I am trying to create an regular expression where I can find a group of specific words or numbers in any order, but this group can contain no other words or numbers unless it the selected words or number. Punctuation and spaces is fine

example:

the word I am searching for is `one,three,four`

`one,three,four apple is red.` should be match

`four, three, one orange is orange.` should be match

`one,four,three the sky is blue.` should be match

`one,two,four,three` should not be match
because two is between the group of words

`four,one,eight,green,three` also not because eight and green is between the group of selected words

I have done some research and found that there is a way to match if a statement have a group of words in any order

[Regex: I want this AND that AND that... in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533408/regex-i-want-this-and-that-and-that-in-any-order)

The only problem with that is if I put a word that is not part of selected group in between the group that will also be consider match. I don't want that.

So I did some more research and found out how to selected specific words and found this

https://superuser.com/questions/903168/how-should-i-write-a-regex-to-match-a-specific-word

It works when one of the selected words are allow like the following below,

regex = `(?:^|\W)one(?:$|\W)`

I put "one" and it found one

I put "three two four one", It also find one

but when I put both expression together. I get this

`^(?:^|\W)one(?:$|\W)(?:^|\W)three(?:$|\W)(?:^|\W)four(?:$|\W).*$`

But it find nothing, what I do wrong?

three two four, It find nothing

The website I use is http://regexr.com/

Comment: **Clarify your question**

Comment: Is the delimiter `,` always comma?

Comment: Yes the delimiter is always a comma

Comment: check out the answer and correct me if you see any mistake

Comment: Why `one,four,three the sky is blue.` isn't a valid sentence?

Comment: It not valid. It a silly example. The main person is to find the one,four,three

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte it should be match, that was my mistake with edit, sorry

Comment: Add a tag for the language or tool in which you will write your regex.

Answer (score 0):

based on what you comment me *Yes the delimiter is always a comma*, you can use **negative look-ahead assertion** to prevent more than 3 `,` if exist like:

## [`^\w+\s*(.)\s*\w+\s*\1\s*\w+(?:(?!\1).)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/DNZuNX/3)

here I picked up the delimiter by using capture-group by use can use it directly like:

## `^\w+\s*,\s*\w+\s*,\s*\w+(?:(?!,).)*$`

or:

with string literal:

`^(?:one|three|four)\s*,\s*(?:one|three|four)\s*,\s*(?:one|three|four).*$`

```js
const regex = /^(?:one|three|four)\s*,\s*(?:one|three|four)\s*,\s*(?:one|three|four).*$/gm;
const str = `one,three,four apple is red.       match

four, three, one orange is orange. match

one,four,three the sky is blue.    match

one,two,four,three not match

four,one,eight,green,three no match`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: it not working for some reason. I try the first example, my test string is one,two,three. No match found

Comment: @LearnerMan Please be more specific. For what reason?

Comment: ^\w+\s*(.)\s*\w+\s*\1\s*\w+(?:(?!\1).)*$ was my regex and "one,two,three" is the string. I test it, but there no result

Comment: @LearnerMan Let me check it out

Comment: @LearnerMan okey try thes: `(?:one|three|four)\s*,\s*(?:one|three|four)\s*,\s*(?:one|three|four).*` you need to use `|` operator

Comment: @LearnerMan on regexr.com **turn on** g and m flag

Comment: that would match "one,one,one"

Comment: yes, if the selected string "one,one,one" As long it match only the selected string I fine.

Comment: @LearnerMan okay if the answer is correct let me know so that I can fixed it that what pattern work for you: **first one** or **second one**

Answer (score 0):

A combination of alternation `|` and negative lookaheads `(?!..)` with backreferences `\n` should do it:

`(one|three|four)\s*,\s*(?!\1)(one|three|four)\s*,\s*(?!\1|\2)(one|three|four)`

You just match one legal value, then in the next sequence you do it again, but this time there's a negative lookahead to preclude what you already matched (which you represent with backreferences).

https://regex101.com/r/FwzBY9/1/