# Multiple regex checks on same string with no overlapping results, while ignoring words

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string in which I want to check for the existence of 2 different types of item. These two types are not mutually exclusive, so I want to also avoid overlap. They can also occur in any order. There are also words within the string that should be ignored, even though they fit the regex pattern.

1. There must be one alpha only item, one to many characters: `[a-zA-Z]+`.
2. Another item needs to be alphanumeric, also one to many characters: `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`.
3. The alphanumeric item cannot also satisfy the criteria of the alpha-only item, and vice versa.
4. The items in an exclusion list should be ignored.

I tried following the post [Regex: I want this AND that AND that... in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533408/regex-i-want-this-and-that-and-that-in-any-order), but I still can't figure out how to exclude the words I need, and I could not figure out how to leverage that answer so that one word didn't satisfy both alphanumeric and alpha only criteria.

This is what I'm currently doing, and it seems to be working, just not very concise. If possible, I'd like to learn how I can expand this out to a single regex check. Apart from not being super concise, I feel that regex will be safer down the road in case I end up needing to add more conditions.

```
bool bHasAlpha = false;
bool bHasAlphaNum = false;
string Test = "123 ABC SomeWord A12";   //The string to check against.
string[] RemoveWords { "ABC", "DEF" };  //I don't want these matches to count, if found.  

//Split my string into "tokens" and check each individually, ignoring the RemoveWords.
string[] TestTokens = Test.Split(' ')
            .Select(s => s)
            .Where(w => !RemoveWords.Contains(w, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            .ToArray();

foreach (string s in TestTokens)
{
    //Is this item alpha-only? (Checking this before alphanumeric)
    if (!bHasAlpha && Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$"))
        bHasAlpha = true;
    //Is this item alphanumeric?
    else if (!bHasAlphaNum && Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"))
        bHasAlphaNum = true;
}

if (bHasAlpha && bHasAlphaNum)
    Console.WriteLine("String Passes!");
```

In the test code above, the string would pass because "123" is caught by the alphanumeric check, and "SomeWord" is caught by the alpha-only check. "ABC" was not because I purposely ignore it.

Examples of strings that should fail:

- `"123 abc 456"` (abc ignored, no valid alpha-only item)
- `"X"` (X can satisfy either alpha or alphanumeric, not both)
- `"ABC DEF 123 456"` (ABC and DEF ignore, no valid alpha-only item)

The following should pass:

- `"ABCDEF 123"` (ABCDEF as a whole word are not considered the same as ABC and DEF separately)
- `"X X"` (2 "words", neither are in the excluded list. One satisfies the alphanumeric criteria, on the alpha-only.)
- `"ABC XYZ ABC DEF A1B2 ABC"` (XYZ is alpha, A1B2 is alphanumeric)
- 123 XYZ (order of the 2 items does not matter. Alpha-only can be 2nd)

Comment: You might keep a count on the items that are alphanumeric and one on the ones that are alpha-only and base your 'IF' on that. Like 'if countAlphaNumeric > 1' ...

Comment: Did you try this : "[a-zA-Z]+(.+)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+(.+)?[a-zA-Z0]+"

Comment: @jdweng - That one finds matches in the 1st and 3rd fail cases. ABC and DEF (case insensitive) should be ignored.

Comment: Do you have the ignore white spaces option set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid a single regex doing all these would be overly complicated if possible at all. However, you may simplify the code by using regexes in two steps:

1. Remove all the words to be ignored with this regex:

   ```
   \b(?:ABC|DEF)\b
   ```
2. Check if the remaining string matches the "alpha & alphanumeric" condition (pseudo code below for the sake of clarity):

   ```
   ALPHA.*ALNUM|ALNUM.*ALPHA
   ```

In C#:

```
var removeRegex = new Regex(@"\b(?:" + string.Join("|", RemoveWords) + @")\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var alpha = @"\b[a-z]+\b";
var alnum = @"\b[a-z0-9]+\b";
var matchRegex = new Regex(string.Format(@"{0}.*{1}|{1}.*{0}", alpha, alnum), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (var s in testStrings)
{
    var ok = matchRegex.Match(removeRegex.Replace(s, "")).Success;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:\t{1}", ok ? "OK" : "Failed", s);
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ms3uKV

Comment: I do like the 2 separate steps better, and it works with my current test cases. Has my approval.

Answer (score 1):

When you found an Alpha item, you need to skip the check.

```
foreach (string s in TestTokens)
{
    //Is this item alpha-only? (Checking this before alphanumeric)
    if (!bHasAlpha && Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$")) // Add !bHasAlpha to skip chekcing if you have found one
        bHasAlpha = true;
    //Is this item alphanumeric?
    else if (Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"))
        bHasAlphaNum = true;
}
```

Comment: Actually just added this to my test code. Will update.

Comment: saw it. And it's more efficient to put `!bHasAlpha` and `!bHasAlphaNum` before the `Regex.IsMatch`