# passsword validation and alert message in Installshield javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, passwords, installshield

Can anyone tell me how to print a message in installshield supported javascript instead of alert?
I tried with the below code but alert is'nt working.
And another problem is that I am unable to validate password by using RegExp.

```
    function Passwordvalidation()
    {
        var password= Session.Property("PASSWORD");
        var patt = new RegExp(":\\[A-Za-z0-9]{6,20}$\\","ig");
        var validpassword = patt.test(password);
        if(validpassword)
            {
                GetMD5(); //calls another function
                return true;
            }
        alert("password should have 6 to 20 characters which contains alphabets and digits between 0 to 9");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I am unable to validate"? Use "^" instead of ":\\". Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions).

Comment: I tried with "^[A-Za-z0-9]{6,20}$" but it did not work.

Comment: See [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/48346033#48346033)

Answer (score 1):

As @some suggested, you should first only check if the regex works.

But reading the error message "*password should have 6 to 20 characters which contains alphabets and digits between 0 to 9*" , I think that this part of the regex `[A-Za-z0-9]{6,20}$` does not do what you think it does.

This matches any uppercase or lowercase character or digit repeated between 6 and 20 times at the end of the string.
This would also match `$$$$$444444` or `aaaaaa`

For example:

```js
var patt = new RegExp('[a-z0-9]{6,20}$', "i");
var passwords = [
  "aaaaaa",
  "333333",
  "a12b3c",
  "AAAAAA",
  "$$$$$444444"
];

for (var i = 0; i < passwords.length; i++) {
  console.log(passwords[i] + " : " + patt.test(passwords[i]));
}
```

With `^`:

```js
var patt = new RegExp('^[a-z0-9]{6,20}$', "i");
var passwords = [
  "aaaaaa",
  "333333",
  "a12b3c",
  "AAAAAA",
  "$$$$$444444"
];

for (var i = 0; i < passwords.length; i++) {
  console.log(passwords[i] + " : " + patt.test(passwords[i]));
}
```

The modifier `i` makes it case insensitive, so you could update your regex to `[a-z0-9]{6,20}$` or `[A-Z0-9]{6,20}$`
You can also omit the `g` modifier to [prevent wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-does-a-regexp-with-global-flag-give-wrong-results).

Comment: Yes [A-Za-z0-9]{6,20} works well as per the requirement.I have mistaken in alert message.So any other suggestions?

Comment: The regexp is wrong. That is one of the problems. It should probably be `/^[A-Za-z0-9]{6,20}$/`

Comment: The OP commented "I tried with "^[A-Za-z0-9]{6,20}$" but it did not work.". It is not clear how exactly it was tried.

Comment: /^[A-Za-z0-9]{6,20}$/ - Tried with this regex also.

Comment: @Thefourthbird
function PasswordValidation()
{
var Passwordportal = Session.Property("PASSWORDPORTAL");
var patt = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{6,20}$/;
var passvalid = patt.test(Passwordportal);
if (passvalid)
{
GetMd5();
Session.Property("PASSVALIDFLAG") = "0"; 
return true;
}

Comment: What does `var Passwordportal` contain? Can you check with `console.log(Passwordportal);console.log(typeof Passwordportal);`?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because `var patt = new RegExp(":\\[A-Za-z0-9]{6,20}$\\","ig");` throws an exception since that is an illegal regexp.

You don't need to use `new RegExp` but can define it as a literal regexp:

```
var patt = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{6,20}$/;
```

Since you defined ranges A-Z and a-z you don't need the i flag, and you don't need the g flag either.

Comment: I tried as you mentioned but it's not working.Any other suggestions?

Comment: Does *alert* exist? To debug: remove everything in your function but the *alert*-call. If that doesn't work, then problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Ya I have tried without alert also.It doesn't works.

Comment: Have your tried with ONLY an alert in your code? `function Passwordvalidation(){alert('Does this work?')}`

Comment: Yes I have tried with/without alert.Both cases don't work with this code.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3533526/2091230) explains password restriction validation with regex really nicely:

> Let's say that we want our password to:
>
> - Contain between 8 and 15 characters
> - Must contain an uppercase letter
> - Must contain a lowercase letter
> - Must contain a digit
> - Must contain one of special symbols
>
> Then we can write a regex like this:
>
> ```
> ^(?=.{8,15}$)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*]).*$
>  \__________/\_________/\_________/\_________/\______________/
>     length      upper      lower      digit        symbol
> ```

Comment: That is not the question.

Comment: Thanks for the infomation but what I actually was asking is my regexp isn't working in installshield javascript. So could you suggest anything else for that?