# Regex: Must have N symbols of type "A" AND must have M symbols of type "B" ... in any order

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

This question is complication of problem in Regex: [I want this AND that AND that… in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533408/regex-i-want-this-and-that-and-that-in-any-order/3533526#3533526). The  [most up-voted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3533526/4818123) of this question is:

```
^(?=.*one)(?=.*two)(?=.*three).*$
```

Now what if I need to check not only characters set, but also quantity of characters of certain kind?
For example:

- At least two uppercase Latin letters
- At least two lowercase Latin letters
- At least two digits
- At least two of specified special characters

... is any order.

I have no idea where from to begin because I don't understand what `?=.` doing in our case.

Comment: _“I have no idea where from to begin because I don't understand what `?=.` doing in our case”_ — See [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/4642212) and use regex debuggers like [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: Just as a hint, to assert that two or more uppercase letters occurs, you could add another positive lookahead: `(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])` ... and do something similar for the other requirements.

Comment: @user4642212, done. My language is Type/JavaScript.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you for the hint. Would you please how is will be for three and more case? It's unobvious for me how to scale your solution from 2 to n cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to handle the additional four requirements would be to just add additional positive lookahead assertions:

```
^
    (?=.*one)                                             match "one" (in any order)
    (?=.*two)                                             match "two"
    (?=.*three)                                           match "three"
    (?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z])                          two uppercase letters
    (?=[^a-z]*[a-z][^a-z]*[a-z])                          two lowercase letters
    (?=\D*\d\D*\d)                                        two digits
    (?=[A-Za-z0-9]*[^A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*[^A-Za-z0-9])  two symbols (two non alphanumeric)
    .*                                                    consume the input
$
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you for the answer! In the case of three uppercase letters, `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z])` will be?

Comment: Why we need `[^A-Z]`? `[^A-Z]*[A-Z]` means "0 or more non-uppercase symbols, then uppercase letter"... Why just `[A-Z]` is invalid?

Comment: For ease of reading, you could use: `(?=.*?[A-Z].*?[A-Z])` ... it is saying to assert that we can look forward and see two capital letters, anywhere in the string.

Comment: O'K, got it! Thank you for the answer and comments!