# Regex search string contains with specific count of letter

Tags: regex

I am trying to workout the regex for searching string which satisfies count of letters where not in specific order

such as:

```
AAABBBCCCDDD
BBBAAADDDCCC
CCCAAABBBDDD
```

are TRUE:

so far, I have got `A{3}B{3}C{3}D{3}` would matches the first line, but for other lines would be needing different order.

is there any great solution that would work out?

Comment: What is the regex library? .NET? PCRE?

Comment: There's more information in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533408/regex-i-want-this-and-that-and-that-in-any-order) if you want to look at an alternate solution.

Comment: Do you want to match a `DDDDDDDDDDDD` string?

Comment: I am using Python

Comment: yes at some points, but not for this question

Answer (score 2):

You can match and capture a letter, then backreference that captured character. Repeat the whole thing as many times as needed, which looks to be 4 here:

```
(?:([A-Z])\1{2}){4}
```

https://regex101.com/r/vrQVgD/1

If the same character can't appear as a sequence more than once, I don't think this can be done in such a DRY manner, you'll need separate capture groups:

```
([A-Z])\1{2}(?!\1)([A-Z])\2{2}(?!\1|\2)([A-Z])\3{2}(?!\1|\2|\3)([A-Z])\4{2}
```

https://regex101.com/r/vrQVgD/2

which is essentially 4 of a variation on the below put together:

```
(?!\1|\2|\3)([A-Z])\4{2}
```

The `(?!\1|\2|\3)` checks that the next character hasn't occurred in any of the previously matched capture groups.

Comment: I may have to search letters with different count rather than 4 for all.
Also may have to find a string which would consists with more than 40 different chars with different count.

Comment: If they're that dynamic, if you want DRY code, I think a regex alone probably wouldn't be the right approach. You could match (any) sequential character sequences with `findAll` and then iterate through the matches programatically.