# Is there a regular expression for "match the following in any order" or "match any permutation"?

Tags: regex, string, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

Gives a set of regular expressions **r_1**, **r_2**, **r_3**, ..., **r_n** is there a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) which could be interpreted to say something similar to:

- match any permutation of **r_1**, **r_2**, **r_3**, ..., **r_n**
- match all of the following in any order: **r_1**, **r_2**, **r_3**, ..., **r_n**

---

The regular expression `a|b|c`...

- matches the letter `a`
- matches the letter `b`
- does not match the entire string `cab`. The regex will only align with exactly one letter from `cab`

For a given example, I could write down each and every permutation. The following is rather verbose:

> `ABC|BAC|CAB|ACB|BCA|CBA`

Comment: What about duplicates? Should they match? Like `aabc`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex: I want this AND that AND that... in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533408/regex-i-want-this-and-that-and-that-in-any-order)

Answer (score 3):

Use a combination of look aheads and length:

```
^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c).{3}$
```

This approach scales linearly, ie the regex has length O(n), when adding more terms, even though the permutations it matches grow factorially, ie O(n!)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
^(?=[A-C]{3}$)(?!.*(.).*\1).*$
```

Here's a [link](https://regex101.com/r/Qc5ztc/1) to play around with it on regex101.com