# Extract two words regardless of order In Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, combinations

I have a Google Sheets table with input in column `A`, and I'd want to achieve this result using `REGEXEXTRACT`.

Desired result:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| Stock OutNew21554 - Shirt - Red | New | Stock Out |
| NewStock Out54872 - Shirt - Green | New | Stock Out |

This is what I attempted.

**01**

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A2, "[(Stock Out)|(New)]+"))
```

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| Stock OutNew21554 - Shirt - Red | Stock OutNew |
| NewStock Out54872 - Shirt - Green | NewStock Out |

**02**

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A3, "(Stock Out)|(New)+"))
```

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| Stock OutNew21554 - Shirt - Red | Stock Out |
| NewStock Out54872 - Shirt - Green |  |

Comment: Why do you add backquotes to tables?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73834069/is-there-a-regulair-expression-for-match-the-following-in-any-order-or-match (Lookarounds not available in re2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two instances of `regexextract()` in an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276), wrapped in `iferror()`:

```
=arrayformula( iferror( 
  { 
    regexextract(A2:A3, "New"), 
    regexextract(A2:A3, "Stock Out") 
  } 
) )
```

Comment: Hi -- thank you for the response, I wonder if one `regexextract()` can get the result? I removed `iferror()` to test.

Comment: The question does not specify the need to use just one `regexextract()`, and that limitation seems a bit artificial. It would be understandable if you did not know the number of result columns, i.e., the number of extractions, in advance, but the desired results you show suggest that do you know that.

Comment: Do you suggest to edit the question or add another one?

Comment: This question already has an answer with a vote, so the best practice is to post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Wouldn't the desired results suggest that it is just a [mre]? The title says "multiple words" and not just two words?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to this in a single `regex` without [generating all possible permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73765831/) or [without lookaround support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73834069/). However, we can call `regexextract`  repeatedly using `REDUCE`. For eg, to extract, `New`,`Stock` and `Color`,

```
=BYROW(A2:A3,LAMBDA(row,TEXTJOIN(" | ",1,REDUCE(,{"New","Stock Out","Red|Green"},LAMBDA(a,c,{a;IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(row,c))})))))
```

This supports unlimited[<sup>☨</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73815258/what-factors-determine-the-memory-used-in-lambda-functions) number of words to extract.

| Output |
| --- |
| New | Stock Out | Red |
| New | Stock Out | Green |

Comment: Thanks @themaster its much needed workaround, I adjusted it to be case insensitive and separated groups like this `=BYROW(A2:A4,LAMBDA(row,TEXTJOIN(" | ",1,REDUCE("",{"new","Stock Out","Red|Black|Green"},LAMBDA(a,c,{a;IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(row,"(?i)"&c))})))))`

Comment: Nice! I think that will always get `New` even when not present in data. How about `reduce( iferror(1/0), { "New", "Stock Out", "Red|Green" }...`?

Comment: @doubleunary does it work the same as `REDUCE("",{...` ?

Comment: @Osm I don't use `iferror`

Comment: What did you use from doubleunary comment?

Comment: @Osm The ``initial value`` for ``reduce`` will always be present in output, even without `regexextract`. The `initial_value` is `New`. I just moved it into the `array` argument and made the `initial_value` empty. See post revisions.

Comment: I see `iferror(1/0)` is the same as `REDUCE("",{...` or `REDUCE(,{...`. @TheMaster

Comment: @Osm Yes, your formula also does it correctly.