# Multiple find & replace with inclusions and exclusions

Tags: google-sheets, replace, google-sheets-formula

I need to search and replace multiple text strings in phrases. The search strings should be chosen per criteria known as Sites. There is an "include" criterion and an "exclude" criterion.

1. **Criteria**

   | RowNo | List Set (A) | Values for Search (B) | Values for Replace (C) | Inclusions (D) | Exclusions (E) | Search (F) | Replace (G) |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | (8) | Anime Set | Scenes | Anime Scenes |  |  | `=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA("^("&QUERY(B8:B,"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")&")$\|^("&QUERY(B8:B,"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")&")(,)\|(,)("&QUERY(B8:B,"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")&")(,)\|(,)("&QUERY(B8:B,"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")&")$"),)` | `=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA("$4$7"&QUERY(C8:C,"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")&"$3$6"),)` |
   | (9) | Anime Set | Facts | Facts about Anime | Site 1 |  |  |  |
   | (10) | Anime Set | Memes | Memes from Anime |  | Site 1 |  |  |
   | (11) | Movie Set | Scenes | Scenes from Movie |  |  |  |  |
   | (12) | Movie Set | Facts | Movie Facts | Site 2 | Site 3 |  |  |
   | (13) | Movie Set | Memes | Movie Memes |  |  |  |  |
   | (14) | Music Set | Facts | Facts about Music |  |  |  |  |
   | (15) | Music Set | Festival | Music Festival | Site 4 |  |  |  |
   | (16) | Music Set | App | Music App |  | Site 4 |  |  |
2. **Source data and desired results**:

   | RowNo | List Set (H) | Belonging (I) | Texts (J) | Replaced Texts (K) |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | (8) | Anime Set |  | Scenes,Facts,Memes | Anime Scenes,Facts,Memes from Anime |
   | (9) | Anime Set | Site 1 | Scenes,Facts,Memes | Anime Scenes,Facts about Anime,Memes |
   | (10) | Movie Set |  | Scenes,Facts,Memes | Scenes from Movie,Facts,Movie Memes |
   | (11) | Movie Set | Site 2 | Scenes,Facts,Memes | Scenes from Movie,Movie Facts,Movie Memes |
   | (12) | Movie Set | Site 3 | Scenes,Facts,Memes | Scenes from Movie,Facts,Movie Memes |
   | (13) | Music Set |  | Facts,Festival,App | Facts about Music,Festival,Music App |
   | (14) | Music Set | Site 4 | Facts,Festival,App | Facts about Music,Music Festival,App |

The phrases to process are in column **Texts (J)** and the desired results are in column **Replaced Texts (K)**.

**Some explanations:**

- Depending on the list set and belonging, search and replace values are applied to the texts;
- As you can see above in the table, cells K8 and K9 are distinguished by belonging, but not by list set - so the `Facts` value is replaced to `Facts about Anime` only for `Site 1`(K9, not K8) (in the Table 1, this value is in inclusions and is only applied to texts if there is an belonging match);
- Another example with cells K11 and K12: in cell K11 the value Facts is replaced (because it is in the inclusions), but in cell K12 this value is ignored (because it is in the exclusions for this belonging).

**Possibly related question**

- [Google Sheets multiple search and replace from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411105/google-sheets-multiple-search-and-replace-from-a-list)

##### Formula I tried(K8):

```
=IFERROR(LAMBDA(data,re,with,BYROW(data,LAMBDA(r,IF(r="","",REDUCE(r,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(re)),LAMBDA(ini,v,REGEXREPLACE(ini,INDEX(re,v),INDEX(with,v))))))))(QUERY(J8:J,"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"),QUERY(A8:I,"SELECT Col6 WHERE Col6 IS NOT NULL AND Col1 IS NOT NULL AND Col1 MATCHES '("&$A$5&")'"),QUERY(A8:I,"SELECT Col7 WHERE Col7 IS NOT NULL AND Col1 IS NOT NULL AND Col1 MATCHES '("&$A$5&")'")),)
```

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: Fixed what I could. If I find mistakes, I will fix them again.

Comment: Can you show a more realistic-looking example, i.e., `campaign` instead of `S_Word1` and so on? Can you also show some source data and the desired result after it has been transformed as specified by the search and replace strings you show in the above tables? Also make sure you are not asking an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676).

Comment: Please add an expected output table containing values that are expected from  the formula for the given input.

Comment: Fixed it. Sorry, I'm a little confused myself.

Comment: Much better. If you can, please [edit] to explain why k8 is ``Anime Scenes,Facts,Memes from Anime`` and k9 is `Anime Scenes,Facts about Anime,Memes`(Any 2 sample explanations). That would help to make your question understanding a bit easier.

Comment: Added some explanations.

Comment: Could you define your desired output based on your input? (ie. **not** based on your trial formulas) Defining your question with failed formula would make sense if your question was why a certain formula fails to work or why it gives a certain error. This is not the case. Aside, if you are particular with using `query`, you are still able to add that a (one-line) requirement.

Comment: @Argyll I believe the section "What I expect to see § some explanations" clarifies the issue based on inputs and not on formulas.

Comment: @TheMaster: "so the Facts value is replaced only for Site 1 (in the Table 1, this value is in inclusions and is only applied to texts if there is an belonging match)" <-- I don't know what that means.    I assume the trial formulas can explain it via section "Formula 3 should work as follows". But trial formulas are just that. It'd be poor at communicating intent.

Comment: For the record, You should always add what you've tried, but in this case, it's very long and distracts from the actual question and it looks better removed.

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks for correcting and explaining (first time here). I haven't checked the solutions in the answers yet, I don't have any free time yet.

Comment: Does the formula take into account that inclusions/exclusions can contain several sites (in one cell, for example, listed separated by commas)? I mean that the filtering should check for a site match, not a match of the exact text of the inclusions/exclusions cell. This is optional, but is it possible?

Comment: In my answer, no it doesn't, but should be possible

Comment: Please do not present new requirements after you have received an answer. Ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead.

Comment: The question mentioned site/belonging match. In early versions of the question, Table 1 even listed several sites in inclusions and exclusions. This moment was simply missed during the editing process.

Comment: Please observe that Stack Exchange sites are not "help forums" nor "discussion boards" but **wiki** sites that use the Q&A format. Further, there is not enough information in the post to answer the new multi-site question. It would be best to post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) showing _realistic-looking_ sample data and your _manually entered_ desired results.

Comment: Indeed, [Rev#3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78066685/3) does show multiple sites, but it wasn't removed by other editors, but you. Once answers are posted based on the current revision, it is generally frowned upon to edit questions or add new requirements. Having said that, I'm sure what you require is easy and you'd be able to figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a filter to filter by List set, inclusions, and exclusions to create the needed search and replace regexes

```
=TOROW( 
  FILTER($B$8:$C$16,
    H8=$A$8:$A$16,//List set filter 
    (I8=$D$8:$D$16)+($D$8:$D$16=""),//Inclusions filter
    ($E$8:$E$16<>I8)+(I8="")// Exclusions filter
))
```

- Use sequential regexreplace using `REDUCE` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74005587/extract-two-words-regardless-of-order-in-google-sheets/74018091)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( 
  MAP(J8:J14,I8:I14,H8:H14, 
    LAMBDA(j,i,h,
      REDUCE(j,
        BYROW( 
          FILTER($B$8:$C$16,
            h=$A$8:$A$16,
            (i=$D$8:$D$16)+($D$8:$D$16=""),
            ($E$8:$E$16<>i)+(i="")
          ),
          LAMBDA(r, JOIN("",r))
        ), 
        LAMBDA(a,c,
          LET(
            arr,TOCOL(SPLIT(c,"",0)),
            rgx,INDEX(arr,1), 
            repl,INDEX(arr,2),
            REGEXREPLACE(a,rgx,repl)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: There is a lack of checking for partial rather than complete matches of sites in inclusions and exclusions. The rest seems to work great at first glance. I haven't done any serious tests yet.

Comment: @StesMus You  just need to adapt `=`  comparison function to `REGEXMATCH`  function  here ``(i=$D$8:$D$16)`` and here ``($E$8:$E$16<>i)`` in the filter calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()`, `reduce()` and `substitute()`, like this:

```
=let( 
  get_, lambda(a, filter(a, len(H8:H))), 
  map(get_(H8:H), get_(I8:I), get_(J8:J), lambda(set, site, phrase, let( 
    includedSearchWords, filter( 
      B8:C, 
      A8:A = set, 
      (D8:D = site) + (D8:D = ""), 
      (E8:E <> site) + (E8:E = "") 
    ), 
    searchFor, choosecols(includedSearchWords, 1), 
    replaceWith, choosecols(includedSearchWords, 2), 
    join(",", map(split(phrase, ","), lambda(text, 
      reduce(text, sequence(rows(searchFor)), lambda(t, i, 
        substitute(t, index(searchFor, i), index(replaceWith, i)) 
      )) 
    ))) 
  ))) 
)
```

The formula goes to cell `K8` in the table:

| List Set (A) | Values for Search (B) | Values for Replace (C) | Inclusions (D) | Exclusions (E) |  |  | List Set (H) | Belonging (I) | Texts (J) | Replaced Texts (K) |  | (desired results) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anime Set | Scenes | Anime Scenes |  |  |  |  | Anime Set |  | Scenes,Facts,Memes | Anime Scenes,Facts,Memes from Anime |  | Anime Scenes,Facts,Memes from Anime |
| Anime Set | Facts | Facts about Anime | Site 1 |  |  |  | Anime Set | Site 1 | Scenes,Facts,Memes | Anime Scenes,Facts about Anime,Memes |  | Anime Scenes,Facts about Anime,Memes |
| Anime Set | Memes | Memes from Anime |  | Site 1 |  |  | Movie Set |  | Scenes,Facts,Memes | Scenes from Movie,Facts,Movie Memes |  | Scenes from Movie,Facts,Movie Memes |
| Movie Set | Scenes | Scenes from Movie |  |  |  |  | Movie Set | Site 2 | Scenes,Facts,Memes | Scenes from Movie,Movie Facts,Movie Memes |  | Scenes from Movie,Movie Facts,Movie Memes |
| Movie Set | Facts | Movie Facts | Site 2 | Site 3 |  |  | Movie Set | Site 3 | Scenes,Facts,Memes | Scenes from Movie,Facts,Movie Memes |  | Scenes from Movie,Facts,Movie Memes |
| Movie Set | Memes | Movie Memes |  |  |  |  | Music Set |  | Facts,Festival,App | Facts about Music,Festival,Music App |  | Facts about Music,Festival,Music App |
| Music Set | Facts | Facts about Music |  |  |  |  | Music Set | Site 4 | Facts,Festival,App | Facts about Music,Music Festival,App |  | Facts about Music,Music Festival,App |
| Music Set | Festival | Music Festival | Site 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Music Set | App | Music App |  | Site 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

See
[let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535),
[lambda()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718),
[map()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985),
[split()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136),
[filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197),
[choosecols()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13197914),
[sequence()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244),
[reduce()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597),
[substitute()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215)
and
[join()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3094077).

Comment: This option is not entirely suitable: 1) it shifts the array if there is no list set in column H; 2) does not work with regular expressions, which is very important (with those formulas in columns F and G, and not in columns B and C).

Comment: Hmm... the formula in the answer exactly matches the desired results you show. It indeed completely ignores sample data rows where column H is blank. There are no such rows in the sample data, and I do not think you specified what the result should be when List Set is blank. It would be best to post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) that specifies the new requirements and shows _realistic-looking_ sample data together with your _manually entered_ desired results.