# PHP regexp for "start of string or pattern"

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Is there a way (other than by doing two separate pattern matches) to use preg_match in PHP to test for either the beginning of the string or a pattern? More specifically I often find myself wanting to test that I have a matching pattern which is not preceded by something, as in

```
preg_match('/[^x]y/', $test)
```

(that is, match y if it is not preceded by x), but to also match y if it occurs at the start of $test (when it also isn't preceded by x, but isn't preceded by any character, so the [^x] construct won't work as it always requires a character to match it.

There's a similar problem at the end of strings, to determine whether a pattern occurs that is not followed by some other pattern.

Comment: Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092797/how-does-the-regular-expression-work

Answer (score 10):

You can simply use standard alternation syntax:

```
/(^|[^x])y/
```

This will match a `y` that is preceded either by the start of the input or by any character other than `x`.

Of course in this specific instance, where the alternative to the `^` anchor is so simple, you can also very well use [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/(?<!x)y/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$name = "johnson";
preg_match("/^jhon..n$/",$name);
```

^ is locates to starting 
and 
$ is locates to ending of string

Answer (score 0):

```
    You need following negate rules:-

--1--^(?!-) is a negative look ahead assertion, ensures that string does not start with specified chars

--2--(?<!-)$ is a negative look behind assertion, ensures that string does not end with specified chars
```

Say you want to have staring that doesn't start with 'start' and end with 'end' strings:-

```
Your Pattern is  :
```

$pattern = '/^(?!x)([a-z0-9]+)$(?

```
 $pattern = '/^(?!start)([a-z0-9]+)$(?<!end)/';

$strArr = array('start-pattern-end','allpass','start-pattern','pattern-end');


 foreach($strArr as $matstr){ 
     preg_match($pattern,$matstr,  $matches);
     print_R( $matches);
 }

This will output :allpass only as it doen't start with 'start' and end with 'end' patterns.
```