# Question about reversing a string

Tags: java, string, reverse

i am trying to do a simple string manipulation. input is "murder", i want to get "murderredrum".

i tried this

```
String str = "murder";
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(str);
// buf is now "murder", so i append the reverse which is "redrum"
buf.append(buf.reverse());
System.out.println(buf);
```

but now i get "redrumredrum" instead of "murderredrum".

can someone explain what's wrong with my program? thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### The short answer

The line:

```
buf.append(buf.reverse());
```

essentially does the following:

```
buf.reverse();    // buf is now "redrum"
buf.append(buf);
```

This is why you get `"redrumredrum"`.

That is, `buf.reverse()` doesn't return a new `StringBuffer` which is the reverse of `buf`. It returns `buf`, after it had reversed itself!

There are many ways to "fix" this, but the easiest would be to explicitly create a new `StringBuffer` for the reversal, so something like this:

```
buf.append(new StringBuffer(str).reverse());
```

---

#### Deeper insight: comparing `String` and `StringBuffer`

`String` in Java is *immutable*. On the other hand, `StringBuffer` is *mutable* (which is why you can, among other things, `append` things to it).

This is why with `String`, a transforming method really returns a *new* `String`. This is why something like this is "wrong"

```
String str = "murder";
str.toUpperCase(); // this is "wrong"!!!
System.out.println(str); // still "murder"
```

Instead you want to do:

```
String str = "murder";
str = str.toUpperCase(); // YES!!!
System.out.println(str); // now "MURDER"!!!
```

However, the situation is far from analogous with `StringBuffer`. Most `StringBuffer` methods do return `StringBuffer`, but they return *the same instance that it was invoked on*! They do *NOT* return a new `StringBuffer` instance. In fact, you're free to discard the "result", because these methods have already accomplished what they do through various mutations (i.e. side effects) to the instance it's invoked upon.

These methods *could've* been declared as `void`, but the reason why they essentially `return this;` instead is because it facilitates [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method%5Fchaining), allowing you to write something like:

```
sb.append(thisThing).append(thatThing).append(oneMoreForGoodMeasure);
```

#### Related questions

- [Method chaining - why is it a good practice, or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103985/method-chaining-why-is-it-a-good-practice-or-not)
- [Fluent Interfaces - Method Chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293353/fluent-interfaces-method-chaining)

---

#### Appendix: `StringBuffer` vs `StringBuilder`

Instead of `StringBuffer`, you should generally prefer `StringBuilder`, which is faster because it's not `synchronized`. Most of the discussions above also applies to `StringBuilder`.

From the documentation:

> [`StringBuffer`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) : A *thread-safe*, mutable sequence of characters. [...] As of JDK 5, this class has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, `StringBuilder`, which should generally be preferred as it supports all of the same operations but faster, as it performs no synchronization.
>
> [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) : A mutable sequence of characters. [...] Instances of `StringBuilder` are not safe for use by multiple threads. If such synchronization is required then it is recommended that `StringBuffer` be used.

#### Related questions

- [StringBuilder and StringBuffer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer-in-java)

---

#### Bonus material! Alternative solution!

Here's an alternative "fix" to the problem that is perhaps more readable:

```
StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder("murder");
StringBuilder worddrow = new StringBuilder(); // starts empty

worddrow.append(word).append(word.reverse());

System.out.println(worddrow); // "murderredrum"
```

Note that while this should do fine for short strings, it does use an extra buffer which means that it's not the most efficient way to solve the problem.

#### Related questions

- [Reverse a string in Java, in O(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109914/reverse-a-string-in-java-in-o1) - as a `CharSequence`, yes this can be done!

---

#### Bonus material again! The last laugh!

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("ha");
sb.append(sb.append(sb));
System.out.println(sb); // "hahahaha"
```

Comment: +1, StringBuffer is mutable. This might be the OP's confusion, because methods like reverse() return a StringBuffer, sort of like String's methods.  But they really mutate the instance and return the instance solely for the convenience of chaining.

Answer (score 1):

buf.reverse() gets called first it modifies the stringbuffer  to redrum. Now you are appending redrum to redrum