# java regex matches loop in reverse direction

Tags: java, regex

I want to match regex pattern in java for particular text. In that while matching I need to find matches in reverse order.

Example:

```
Regex Pattern --  [([^]]*])

Input String  -- [blue][red][green]

Output   --  1st match --->[blue]
             2nd match --->[red]
             3rd match --->[green]
```

But I'm expecting match to be in reverse order.

```
Expected output  --    1st match --->[green]
             2nd match --->[red]
             3rd match --->[blue]
```

Please help how to form the regex to achieve the expected output.

Comment: @ScaryWombat StringBuilder.reverse will reverse the String as whole like this ]neerg[]der[]eulb[. I don't know how it will solve my problem. Please explain me

Comment: Sorry - dumb comment

Comment: want to show some code you have tried.

Comment: Now i achieved by saving matches in ArrayList and reverse the List to get Expected output. But I need to do it in regex part itself. Because in case they are more than 10 matches I need only 10 matches from the last. So I iterate the reverse List for the size upto 10 and break the loop. I don't need to grow list size as it may contain 100 or 1000 matches. I need only last 10.

Comment: That regex doesn't work unless you add some escapes. `[([^]` is a character group matching `(`, `[` or `^`. Next is `]*` matching 0 or more `]`. Next is `]` matching exactly one `]`. Last is `)` which causes `PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')'`.

Comment: This can be done is a single regex, if you don't mind making it large. See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6h6txr/1) for demo.

Comment: in case of 10 the regex looks ok. In case,if my logic shifts to 50 or 100 then it is unmaintainable

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have complied regex date"

```
     ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
            Matcher foo = date.matcher("foo");
            while (foo.matches()) {
                strings.add(foo.group());
            }
            Collections.reverse(strings);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Reverse regular expression in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545250/reverse-regular-expression-in-java) discusses the topic and I posted a solution there, added here for convenience.

If anyone is interested in a Java solution, I implemented a library to do just that. https://github.com/vsch/reverse-regex.

Handles all valid Java regex constructs and provides utility classes to wrap pattern, matcher and input for reverse searches to handle all need mappings and reversals.