# is there a elegant way to parse a word and add spaces before capital letters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i need to parse some data and i want to convert

```
AutomaticTrackingSystem
```

to

```
Automatic Tracking System
```

essentially putting a space before any capital letter (besides the first one of course)

Comment: Why do you even want a regex for this? Using a Stringbuilder and one pass will be much more efficient (and less error-prone).

Comment: @Moron - I dont necessarily want regex (the question didn't state a solution).  i put the regex tag as i thought that was one of the possible solutions.  how would you do it with string builder?

Comment: @ooo: I have added an answer with a possible solution using StringBuilder.

Comment: btw, if you don't necessarily want a regex solution, don't tag it as such!

Comment: @Moron - maybe a little late but i removed the regex tag

Comment: I restored the regex tag because most of the answers--including the accepted one--use regexes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Without regex you can do something like (or perhaps something more concise using LINQ):

(Note: no error checking is there, you should add it)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SO
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String test = "AStringInCamelCase";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (char c in test)
            {
                if (Char.IsUpper(c))
                {
                    sb.Append(" ");
                }
                sb.Append(c);
            }

            if (test != null && test.Length > 0 && Char.IsUpper(test[0]))
            {
                sb.Remove(0, 1);
            }

            String result = sb.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

this gives the output

```
A String In Camel Case
```

Comment: +1 for implementing a sensible and readable solution, instead of blindly going for regexes.

Comment: some great answers in here, but for me its not elegant if it uses regex

Answer (score 32):

You can use lookarounds, e.g:

```
string[] tests = {
   "AutomaticTrackingSystem",
   "XMLEditor",
};

Regex r = new Regex(@"(?!^)(?=[A-Z])");
foreach (string test in tests) {
   Console.WriteLine(r.Replace(test, " "));
}
```

This prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/5b0G2)):

```
Automatic Tracking System
X M L Editor
```

The regex `(?!^)(?=[A-Z])` consists of two assertions:

- `(?!^)` - i.e. we're not at the beginning of the string
- `(?=[A-Z])` - i.e. we're just before an uppercase letter

#### Related questions

- [How do I convert CamelCase into human-readable names in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559759/how-do-i-convert-camelcase-into-human-readable-names-in-java/)
- [How does the regular expression `(?<=#)[^#]+(?=#)` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092797/how-does-the-regular-expression-work/)

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

---

#### Splitting the difference

Here's where using assertions really make a difference, when you have several different rules, and/or you want to `Split` instead of `Replace`. This example combines both:

```
string[] tests = {
   "AutomaticTrackingSystem",
   "XMLEditor",
   "AnXMLAndXSLT2.0Tool",
};

Regex r = new Regex(
   @"  (?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])    # UC before me, UC lc after me
    |  (?<=[^A-Z])(?=[A-Z])        # Not UC before me, UC after me
    |  (?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[^A-Za-z])  # Letter before me, non letter after me
    ",
   RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
);
foreach (string test in tests) {
   foreach (string part in r.Split(test)) {
      Console.Write("[" + part + "]");
   }
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

This prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Qw5iC)):

```
[Automatic][Tracking][System]
[XML][Editor]
[An][XML][And][XSLT][2.0][Tool]
```

#### Related questions

- [Java split is eating my characters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819933/java-split-is-eating-my-characters/)

  - Has many examples of splitting on zero-width matching assertions

Answer (score 4):

I've just written a function to do exactly this. :)

Replace `([a-z])([A-Z])` with `$1 $2` (or `\1 \2` in other languages).

I've also got a replace for `([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])` too - this converts things like "NumberOfABCDThings" into "Number Of ABCD Things"

So in C# this would look something like:

```
Regex r1 = new Regex(@"([a-z])([A-Z])");
Regex r2 = new Regex(@"([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])");

NewString = r1.Replace( InputString , "$1 $2");
NewString = r2.Replace( NewString , "$1 $2");
```

(although possibly there's a more consice way of writing that)

If you might have punctuation or numbers, I guess you could try `([^A-Z])([A-Z])` for the first match.

Hmmm, another way of writing those regexes, using lookbehind and lookahead, is to just match the position and insert a space - i.e. `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])` and `(?<=[A-Z]+)(?=[A-Z][a-z])` and in both cases replace with just " " - not sure whether there may be advantages to that method, but it's an interesting way. :)

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, there's an option for reverse regex :-)  We can now eliminate string reversal, here's another way to do it:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Regex ry = new Regex
              (@"([A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]+[A-Z]|[A-Z]|[^A-Za-z]+[^A-Za-z])", 
              RegexOptions.RightToLeft);


        string[] tests = {
        "AutomaticTrackingSystem",
        "XMLEditor",
        "AnXMLAndXSLT2.0Tool",
        "NumberOfABCDThings",
        "AGoodMan",
        "CodeOfAGoodMan"
        };


        foreach(string t in tests)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n{0} -- {1}", t, ry.Replace(t, " $1"));   
        }

    }


}
```

Output:

```
AutomaticTrackingSystem --  Automatic Tracking System


XMLEditor --  XML Editor


AnXMLAndXSLT2.0Tool --  An XML And XSLT 2.0 Tool


NumberOfABCDThings --  Number Of ABCD Things


AGoodMan --  A Good Man


CodeOfAGoodMan --  Code Of A Good Man
```

Answer (score 0):

If you seek to keep acronyms intact, replace "([^A-Z])([A-Z])" with "\1 \2", 
else replace "(.)([A-Z])" with "\1 \2".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        var rx = new Regex
                (@"([a-z]+[A-Z]|[A-Z][A-Z]+|[A-Z]|[^A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]+)");

        string[] tests = {
        "AutomaticTrackingSystem",
        "XMLEditor",
        "AnXMLAndXSLT2.0Tool",
        "NumberOfABCDThings",
        "AGoodMan",
        "CodeOfAGoodMan"
        };

        foreach(string t in tests)
        {
            string y = Reverse(t);
            string x = Reverse( rx.Replace(y, @" $1") );
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n{0} -- {1}",y,x);    
        }

    }

    static string Reverse(string s)
    {
        var ca = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(ca);
        string t = new string(ca);
        return t;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
metsySgnikcarTcitamotuA -- Automatic Tracking System 


rotidELMX -- XML Editor 


looT0.2TLSXdnALMXnA -- An XML And XSLT 2.0 Tool 


sgnihTDCBAfOrebmuN -- Number Of ABCD Things 


naMdooGA -- A Good Man 


naMdooGAfOedoC -- Code Of A Good Man
```

It works by scanning the string backward, and making the capital letter the terminator.  Wishing there's a parameter for RegEx for scanning the string backwards, so the above  separate string reversal won't be needed anymore :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this linq one-liner: (perfectly works for me)

```
public static string SpaceCamelCase(string input)
{
    return input.Aggregate(string.Empty, (old, x) => $"{old}{(char.IsUpper(x) ? " " : "")}{x}").TrimStart(' ');
}
```