# Exploding UpperCasedCamelCase to Upper Cased Camel Case in PHP

Tags: php, regex, text-processing

Right now, I am implementing this with a split, slice, and implosion:

```
$exploded = implode(' ',array_slice(preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/','ThisIsATest'),1));
//$exploded = "This Is A Test"
```

Prettier version:

```
$capital_split = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/','ThisIsATest');
$blank_first_ignored = array_slice($capital_split,1);
$exploded = implode(' ',$blank_first_ignored);
```

However, the problem is when you have input like `'SometimesPDFFilesHappen'`, which my implementation would (incorrectly) interpret as `'Sometimes P D F Files Happen'`.

How can I (simply) get my script to condense `'P D F'` to `'PDF'`?

My qualification for when it should split would be to start at the first capital, and end one before the last, to accommodate the next word.

Yes, I know there are some ambiguities, like in `'ThisIsAPDFTest'`, which would be interpreted as `'This Is APDF Test'`. However, I can't think of a "smart" way to avoid this, so it is an acceptable compromise.

Comment: See also:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103730/is-there-a-elegant-way-to-parse-a-word-and-add-spaces-before-capital-letters/3103795#3103795

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$input = "SomePDFFile";

$pass1 = preg_replace("/([a-z])([A-Z])/","\\1 \\2",$input);
$pass2 = preg_replace("/([A-Z])([A-Z][a-z])/","\\1 \\2",$pass1);
echo $pass2;
```

or, if you are very religious about having 1 statement:

```
preg_replace("/(([a-z])([A-Z])|([A-Z])([A-Z][a-z]))/","\\2\\4 \\3\\5",$input);
```

which is very ugly.

Comment: +1 you saved me writing a question and then getting slapped for a duplicate.

Comment: ++; Thank you, this passed all my unit tests that other algorithms failed. I really need to learn regex.

Comment: Added a unit test for my own purposes, and replaced the first argument on pass1 with "/([a-z])([A-Z][a-z])/" to prevent "FoO" from being replaced with "Fo O".