# PHP regex add slashes before upper case leter

Tags: php, regex, regular-language

Before: `ThisIsExample` 
After: `This-Is-Example`

It's possible do with regular expression ? I try do this by exploding by upper case letter but it's impossible devide string by upper case leteer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$result = preg_replace('~[a-z]\K(?=[A-Z])~', '-', $yourString);
```

`\K` reset all that have been matched before, then you can with this trick match all uppercase preceded by a lowercase.

`(?=..)` is a lookahead and means *followed by*. A lookahead is just a check but match nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible using a regular expression. Please see this StackOverflow answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6227110
The answer provides a solution to add a underscore before a capital letter, so to add a dash (the - sign), this is the correct code:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\B([A-Z])/', '-$1', $subject);
```

Hope this helps.