# Add underscore in front of capital letters, but only first capital letter if there are multiple in a row

Tags: php, regex, string

Trying to convert something like `WebsiteURL` to `website_url`. I was able to convert it to `website_u_r_l` using this suggestion: [PHP - add underscores before capital letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227061/php-add-underscores-before-capital-letters/6227110)

However, that doesn't work for my requirements. Having a hard time finding a better answer. Maybe the simpler solution is to convert multiple capitals in a row first, so `WebsiteUrl`? Wondering what the most efficient route would be.

Comment: Please show some code you have already tried

Comment: Use this regex: `/(?<![A-Z])(?=[A-Z])/`

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993721/how-to-convert-camelcase-to-camel-case

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo strtolower(preg_replace('%([a-z])([A-Z])%', '\1_\2', "WebsiteURL"));
```

check solution [here](https://www.phprun.org/F3KKC1)

Answer (score 0):

This code below achieves what I think you want to achieve

```
$result = strtolower(preg_replace('/(.)([A-Z])/', '$1_$2', $subject));
```

**Converting**

```
TestTest
testTest
testingTest
```

To:

```
testing_test
test_test
test_test
```

Found at this [src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227061/php-add-underscores-before-capital-letters)

Comment: This was close, but converted `WebsiteURL` to `website_ur_l`

Comment: My mistake, I thought you had `WebsiteUrl` not `WebSiteURL` ! apologies!