# In PHP how do I complete a regex that returns only what was grouped

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

I want to perform a regex using grouping. I am only interested in the grouping, its all I want returned. Is this possible?

```
$haystack = '<a href="/foo.php">Go To Foo</a>';
$needle = '/href="(.*)">/';
preg_match($needle,$haystack,$matches);
print_r($matches);

//Outputs
//Array ( [0] => href="/foo.php">  [1] => /foo.php ) 

//I want:
//Array ( [0] => /foo.php )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is possible with lookarounds. Instead of:

```
href="(.*)">
```

You want

```
(?<=href=").*(?=">)
```

Now this will match (and therefore capture into group 0) any `.*` that is preceded by `href="` and followed by `">`. Note that I highly suspect that you really need `.*?` instead, i.e. reluctant instead of greedy.

```
---A--Z---A--Z----
   ^^^^^^^^^^^
      A.*Z
```

In any case, it looks like PHP's `preg` is PCRE, so it should support lookarounds.

#### regular-expressions.info links

- [Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Flavor comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)

  - PHP's `preg` functions implement the PCRE flavor.
  - PCRE:

    - `(?=regex)` (positive lookahead): YES
    - `(?<=text)` (positive lookbehind): fixed + alternation

---

#### Demonstration

```
<?php

$haystack = '<a href="/foo.php">Go To Foo</a><a href="/bar.php">Go To Bar</a>';
$needle = '/(?<=href=").*?(?=">)/';
preg_match_all($needle,$haystack,$matches);
print_r($matches);     

?>
```

[Running this on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/P5jRM) produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /foo.php
            [1] => /bar.php
        )

)
```

#### Related questions

These are mostly Java, but the regex part covers using lookarounds/assertions:

- [Java split is eating my characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819933/java-split-is-eating-my-characters/)
- [Can you use zero-width matching regex in String split?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406633/can-you-use-zero-width-matching-regex-in-string-split)
- [How do I convert CamelCase into human-readable names in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559759/how-do-i-convert-camelcase-into-human-readable-names-in-java)

Comment: I enjoyed reading this answer, but it does not really answer the original question, since grouping was specifically mentioned.

Comment: Sorry if my question was misleading but this is the answer I really needed. After I got over this hurdle I was going to work on generalizing this regex so it could work with multiple links.  polygenelubricants' answer already anticipated that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No. The 0 index will always be the text that was matches, not the groups. Of course, you can just remove the first element and renumber the array.

Answer (score 1):

You could use  [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) :

```
array_shift($matches);
```

but there is no flag to tell `preg_match` to do what you want.

Anyway, as you know that it will **always** be there, you should be able to handle this in your code.
Why do you want / need this?

Comment: I think you mean "no flag" :p