# Splitting a simple maths expression with regex

Tags: java, regex, math

I am trying to have a regular expression split on equations like 1.5+4.2*(5+2) with operators - + * / so the output would be input into a array so I can parse individually

```
[0]1.5
[1]+
[2]4.2
[3]*
[4](
[5]5
[6]+
[7]2
[8])
```

I have found out that the `\b` will work on `1+2+3` however if I were to have decimal points it would not split.

I have tried splitting with `\b(\.\d{1,2})` however it does not split on the decimal point

Comment: I'm curious as to what you plan to do when you have the different pieces. Could this be another instance where you want to lexically analyze a grammar (lex/yacc), rather than run it through a regex?

Comment: I know it isn't my place to alter the title because of a pet peace of mine, but the fact that some people say "maths" instead of "math" bugs me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((\\d*\\.\\d+)|(\\d+)|([\\+\\-\\*/\\(\\)]))");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher("1.5+4.2*(5+2)/10-4");
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("%s ", m.group());
}

output: 1.5 + 4.2 * ( 5 + 2 ) / 10 - 4
```

You can also use ?: to avoid capturing groups. I left it to make it simple.

Answer (score 18):

You can use zero-width matching lookahead and lookbehind combo as alternates.

```
String equation = "1.5+4.2*(5+2)";

String regex = "(?<=op)|(?=op)".replace("op", "[-+*/()]");

// actual regex becomes (?<=[-+*/()])|(?=[-+*/()])

System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
    equation.split(regex)
));
//  ___  _  ___  _  _  _  _  _  _
// [1.5, +, 4.2, *, (, 5, +, 2, )]
```

#### Explanation

- `[…]` is a character class definition
- `(?<=…)` is a lookbehind; it asserts that we can match `…` to the left
- `(?=…)` is a lookahead; it asserts that we can match `…` to the right
- `this|that` is alternation
- Thus, `(?<=op)|(?=op)` matches everywhere after or before `op`

  - ... where `op` is replaced by `[-+*/()]`, i.e. a character class that matches operators

    - Note that `-` is first here so that it doesn't become a range definition meta character

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [Alternation with Vertical Bar](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

#### Related questions

- [How does the regular expression `(?<=#)[^#]+(?=#)` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092797/how-does-the-regular-expression-work/)
- [Regex: why doesn’t [01-12] range work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148240/regex-why-doesnt-01-12-range-work-as-expected/)

---

#### More examples of zero-width matching regex for splitting

Here are more examples of splitting on zero-width matching constructs; this can be used to split a string but also keep delimiters.

Simple sentence splitting, keeping punctuation marks:

```
String str = "Really?Wow!This.Is.Awesome!";
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
    str.split("(?<=[.!?])")
)); // prints "[Really?, Wow!, This., Is., Awesome!]"
```

Splitting a long string into fixed-length parts, using `\G`

```
String str = "012345678901234567890";
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
    str.split("(?<=\\G.{4})")
)); // prints "[0123, 4567, 8901, 2345, 6789, 0]"
```

Split before capital letters (except the first!)

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
    "OhMyGod".split("(?=(?!^)[A-Z])")
)); // prints "[Oh, My, God]"
```

A variety of examples is provided in related questions below.

#### Related questions

- [Can you use zero-width matching regex in String split?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406633/can-you-use-zero-width-matching-regex-in-string-split)

  - `"abc<def>ghi<x><x>" -> "abc", "<def>", "ghi", "<x>", "<x>"`
- [How do I convert CamelCase into human-readable names in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559759/how-do-i-convert-camelcase-into-human-readable-names-in-java)

  - `"AnXMLAndXSLT2.0Tool" -> "An XML And XSLT 2.0 Tool"`
  - C# version: [is there a elegant way to parse a word and add spaces before capital letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103730/is-there-a-elegant-way-to-parse-a-word-and-add-spaces-before-capital-letters)
- [Java split is eating my characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819933/java-split-is-eating-my-characters/)
- [Is there a way to split strings with String.split() and include the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters/2848147#2848147)
- [Regex split string but keep separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910536/regex-split-string-but-keep-separators)

Comment: Great post, but I was wondering: how would one avoid splitting negative numbers?

Answer (score 3):

Use match, instead of split:

```
(?:\d+\.)?\d*(?:e[+\-]?\d+)?|[\s\-\/()+*%=]
```

This regex will also accept valid floats like: `1.2e+3 * 2` which should equal `2400`. the regexes given by the other respondents will fail.

Comment: Would this work with negative numbers as well? How would you use it in Java in order to split your string?

Answer (score 0):

Split the string using `[+-/*()]`.

Comment: hi,however i also need to include the operators so i cant use the regex you given

Comment: Store the match via enclosing parentheses.