# How can I split a string for mathematical use in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, math, split

I asked a similar question recently, but I need some more help.

The user will be able to enter a string, for example:

```
"-5-1/-2"
```

It needs to: delimit by +,-,*,/,(,)
and negative numbers should be kept together, in this case -5 and -2 should stay together.

This is what I currently have:

```
String userStrWithoutSpaces=userStr.replaceAll(" ", "");
String[] tokens = userStrWithoutSpaces.split("(?<=[\\-+*/=()])|(?=[()\\-+*/=])");
```

Which works besides keeping negative numbers together.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use an actual parser?

Comment: I agree, there are libraries and such made for this

Comment: You're on the right track , so keep that up . Although if you need a quick-fix , parsers!!

Comment: Be aware that most parsers (I believe) for arithmetic expressions consider that minus as a unary operator, rather than as part of the number; normally, it makes things more consistent and easy.

Comment: If you want to parse mathematical expressions like this, the right way to do it is with the [shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). It's surprisingly difficult to do with ordinary kinds of parsers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String[] tokens = userStrWithoutSpaces.split(
    "(?<=[+*/=()])|((?<=-)(?!\\d))|(?=[()\\-+*/=])");
```

This uses a lookahead to not split when hyphen is followed by digit

Answer (score 1):

I would use [JFlex](http://jflex.de/). You need a lexical analyzer, a piece of code, which will give you tokens from some input text. JFlex is a generator of lexical analyzers. **Very fast and reliable** analyzers. You specify only a rules, in a form similiar to regular expressions, *very convenient*. All the low-level job does JFlex. The picture presents idea of JFlex:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Get the result of the arithmetic expression in Java:**

[How to parse a mathematical expression given as a string and return a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432245/java-parse-a-mathematical-expression-given-as-a-string-and-return-a-number)

**Parse it into its number and operator components in java:**

[Splitting a simple maths expression with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373885/splitting-a-simple-maths-expression-with-regex)