# Java Split() to Split Up Math Equation

Tags: java, regex, parsing, split, expression

I am trying to write a method that would split up an inputted math expression into all the individual operators and numbers. For example, 1 + 1 would produce an array of { 1, +, 1 } and 2 - -2 would produce an array of { 2, -, -2 }. I sort of got this working after doing some research on StackOverflow (using this question: [Splitting a simple maths expression with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373885/)) and I wrote the following:

```
String[] t = tokens.split("(?<=[-+*/()])|(?=[-+*/()])");
```

This works great with the 1 + 1, but doing 2 - -2 produces { 2, -, -, 2 }, which is not what I want. I am kind of new to splitting and regexes, so this may be a basic question that I am simply failing to properly research, but any help would be greately appreciated! Also, I realize it would be super easy to just separate by spaces, but I'd really like to avoid that. Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by escaping special characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as you want.

```
String[] t = "2-2+-2".split("(?=[-+*/()])|(?<=[^-+*/][-+*/])|(?<=[()])");
// ==> {"2", "-", "2", "+", "-2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding `[0-9]+` to the beginning of your regex pattern, like so:

```
String[] t = tokens.split("[0-9]+(?<=[-+*/()])|(?=[-+*/()])");
```

you force the first matching expression to precede a series of numbers instead of preceding anything at all. The result is:

```
[2 , - , -2]
```

which is not perfect, but at least you have the right tokens now, after you trim the excess space.

Comment: This works but now 2 - 2 results in { 2, -2 } instead of { 2, -, 2}. Is there a way that it can do both 2 - -2 and 2 - 2?