# problem with java split()

Tags: java, regex

I have a string:

```
strArray= "-------9---------------";
```

I want to find 9 from the string. The string may be like this:

```
strArray= "---4-5-5-7-9---------------";
```

Now I want to find out only the digits from the string. I need the values 9,4, or such things and ignore the '-' .  I tried the following:

```
strArray= strignId.split("-");
```

but it gets error, since there are multiple '-' and I don't get my output. So what function of java should be used?

My input and output should be as follows:

```
input="-------9---------------";
    output="9";
input="---4-5-5-7-9---------------";
    output="45579";
```

What should I do?

Comment: if i want to get the output in an array where each digit will be in a cell then what to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't use split!

Split is to get the things BETWEEN the separator.

For this you want to eliminate the unwanted chars; '-'

The solution is simple

out=in.replaceAll("-","");

Answer (score 19):

The `+` is a regex metacharacter of "one-or-more" repetition, so the pattern `-+` is "one or more dash". This would allow you to use `str.split("-+")` instead, but you may get an empty string as first element.

If you just want to remove all `-`, then you can do `str = str.replace("-", "")`. This uses [`replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method, which performs literal `String` replacement, i.e. not regex patterns.

If you want a `String[]` with each digit in its own element, then it's easiest to do in two steps: first remove all non-digits, then use zero-length assertion to split everywhere that's not the beginning of the string `(?!^)` (to prevent getting an empty string as a first element). If you want a `char[]`, then you can just call [`String.toCharArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29)

Lastly, if the string can be very long, it's better to use a [`java.util.regex.Matcher`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) in a `find()` loop looking for a digit `\d`, or a [`java.util.Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) with a delimiter `\D*`, i.e. a sequence (possibly empty) of non-digits. This will not give you an array, but you can use the loop to populate a [`List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (see *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 25: Prefer lists to arrays*).

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Repetition with Star and Plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

---

#### Snippets

Here are some examples to illustrate the above ideas:

```
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        "---4--5-67--8-9---".split("-+")
    ));
    // [, 4, 5, 67, 8, 9]
    // note the empty string as first element

    System.out.println(
        "---4--5-67--8-9---".replace("-", "")
    );
    // 456789

    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        "abcdefg".toCharArray()
    ));
    // [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
```

The next example first deletes all non-digit `\D`, then splitting everywhere except the beginning of the string `(?!^)`, to get a `String[]` each containing a digit:

```
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        "@*#^$4@!#5ajs67>?<{8_(9SKJDH"
            .replaceAll("\\D", "")
            .split("(?!^)")
    ));
    // [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This uses a `Scanner`, with `\D*` as delimiter, to get each digit as its own token, using it to populate a `List<String>`:

```
    List<String> digits = new ArrayList<String>();
    String text = "(&*!@#123ask45{P:L6";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(text).useDelimiter("\\D*");
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        digits.add(sc.next());
    }
    System.out.println(digits);
    // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

---

### Common problems with `split()`

Here are some common beginner problems when dealing with `String.split`:

#### Lesson #1: `split` takes a regular expression pattern

This is probably the most common beginner mistake:

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
    "one|two|three".split("|")
));
// [, o, n, e, |, t, w, o, |, t, h, r, e, e]

System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
    "not.like.this".split(".")
));
// []
```

The problem here is that `|` and `.` are regex metacharacters, and since they are intended to be matched literally, they need to be escaped by preceding with a backslash, which as a Java string literal is `"\\"`.

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
    "one|two|three".split("\\|")
));
// [one, two, three]

System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
    "not.like.this".split("\\.")
));
// [not, like, this]
```

#### Lesson #2: `split` discards trailing empty strings by default

Sometimes it's desired to keep trailing empty strings (which are discarded by default `split`):

```
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        "a;b;;d;;;g;;".split(";")
    ));
    // [a, b, , d, , , g]
```

Note that there are slots for the "missing" values for `c`, `e`, `f`, but not for `h` and `i`. To fix this, you can use a negative `limit` argument to [`String.split(String regex, int limit)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

```
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        "a;b;;d;;;g;;".split(";", -1)
    ));
    // [a, b, , d, , , g, , ]
```

You can also use a positive `limit` of *n* to apply the pattern at most *n - 1* times (i.e. resulting in no more than *n* elements in the array).

---

#### Zero-width matching `split` examples

Here are more examples of splitting on zero-width matching constructs; this can be used to split a string but also keep "delimiters".

Simple sentence splitting, keeping punctuation marks:

```
    String str = "Really?Wow!This.Is.Awesome!";
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        str.split("(?<=[.!?])")
    )); // prints "[Really?, Wow!, This., Is., Awesome!]"
```

Splitting a long string into fixed-length parts, using `\G`

```
    String str = "012345678901234567890";
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        str.split("(?<=\\G.{4})")
    )); // prints "[0123, 4567, 8901, 2345, 6789, 0]"
```

Split before capital letters (except the first!)

```
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        "OhMyGod".split("(?=(?!^)[A-Z])")
    )); // prints "[Oh, My, God]"
```

A variety of examples is provided in related questions below.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

#### Related questions

- [Can you use zero-width matching regex in String split?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406633/can-you-use-zero-width-matching-regex-in-string-split)

  - `"abc<def>ghi<x><x>" -> "abc", "<def>", "ghi", "<x>", "<x>"`
- [How do I convert CamelCase into human-readable names in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559759/how-do-i-convert-camelcase-into-human-readable-names-in-java)

  - `"AnXMLAndXSLT2.0Tool" -> "An XML And XSLT 2.0 Tool"`
  - C# version: [is there a elegant way to parse a word and add spaces before capital letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103730/is-there-a-elegant-way-to-parse-a-word-and-add-spaces-before-capital-letters)
- [Java split is eating my characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819933/java-split-is-eating-my-characters/)
- [Is there a way to split strings with String.split() and include the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters/2848147#2848147)
- [Regex split string but keep separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910536/regex-split-string-but-keep-separators)

Comment: Holy smoke.  Did you just write this on the spot?  +1 for an excellent response.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this to get the single values splitted.  I'd rather eliminate the unwanted chars first to avoid getting empty/null String in the result array.

```
final Vector nodes = new Vector();
int index = original.indexOf(separator);
while (index >= 0) {
  nodes.addElement(original.substring(0, index));
  original = original.substring(index + separator.length());
  index = original.indexOf(separator);
}
nodes.addElement(original);
final String[] result = new String[nodes.size()];
if (nodes.size() > 0) {
  for (int loop = 0; loop smaller nodes.size(); loop++) {
    result[loop] = (String) nodes.elementAt(loop);
  }
}
return result;
}
```