# Split a string and keep matched splitter in list in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Hey, I have a python background and I'm having a couple of issues with the split function in groovy (but I guess java...). Specifically, I want to retain my split character since I do not know at the time of splitting what it is. So for example, suppose I have the following string:

```
"(if (= 2 (- 3 1)) 4 (- 3 1))"
```

I want to split it into:

```
['', '(', 'if ', '(', '= 2 ', '(', '- 3 1', ')', '', ')', ' 4 ', '(', '- 3 1', ')', '', ')', '']
```

(note: I'm not trying to write a lisp/scheme parser, this is just an easy example of nested parentheses.)

Is there an easy way to do this in Groovy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the fundamental JDK, [this question (and answers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters) implies that it can be done, but not easily (though this is subjective).

That leaves the Groovy JDK. According to the [Groovy JDK doc](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/), particularly the additional methods on String, I don't see anything that gives you what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, @polygenelubricants's crazy, crazy answer does what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really mean splitting the string. From your example it looks more like you are trying to parse it so what you need is a **tokenizer**.
There are plenty solutions available. Information on [lexical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) might be a good point to start.

Comment: Thanks, but I really don't want to take in a huge project just to look at ( and ).

Comment: I understand however it doesn't need to be huge and an interesting part of CS.