# How to split a string with java but also keep the delimiters end of sentance

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to split strings with String.split() and include the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters)

Suppose I have the following sentences-

```
What is your name? My name is Don. You are so nice!
```

I want the output by java as follows

```
What is your name?
My name is Don.
You are so nice!
```

I used the java split() method. but it split without the delimiters. i used `split("[\\.!?]")`

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters -- please remember to search before posted.

Comment: @Nick, that question asks how to split on non alphanumerics, which is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
split("(?<=[.?!])");
```

(Adapted from [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters/2848147#2848147))

Comment: that doesn't remove the space, which I believe the OP wants.

Comment: @Qwerky - The requirement was: split at delimiters (punctuation marks) and keep them. But getting rid of the space(s) in one go, like you showed, is an nice idea (bonus).

Answer (score 0):

You should split on whitespace, with a lookbehind on the '.!?' characters.

```
String s = "What is your name? My name is Don. You are so nice!";

String[] tokens = s.split("(?<=[\\.\\!\\?])\\s");

for (String t : tokens) System.out.println(t);
```