# How can I split a string into words, spaces and newlines?

Tags: java, string, split

I'm using the Play Framework and taking a text from a textarea and I want to split it into an array of the words, spaces and newlines that was entered.

> Hello World How
>
> Are You

Would be something like

```
a[0] = "Hello";
a[1] = " ";
a[2] = "World";
a[3] = " ";
a[4] = "How";
a[5] = "\n";
a[6] = "Are";
a[7] = " ";
a[8] = "You";
```

If there is a simple regex way or something similar I would love to hear about it?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters

Comment: Aye that might be the solution. Going to look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
st = new java.util.StringTokenizer (text, "[ \t\n]", true)
```

Comment: @Ólafur Waage: *StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is **discouraged** in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split  method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.* From Javadocs: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Answer (score 6):

Try this code:

```
String str = "Hello World How\nAre You";
String[] inputs = str.split("(?!^)\\b");
for (int i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
   System.out.println("a[" + i + "] = \"" + inputs[i] + '"');
}

OUTPUT:
a[0] = "Hello"
a[1] = " "
a[2] = "World"
a[3] = " "
a[4] = "How"
a[5] = "
"
a[6] = "Are"
a[7] = " "
a[8] = "You"
```

Answer (score 0):

[StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) would work.