# How to keep the delimiter while using RegEx?

Tags: java, regex, separator, punctuation

I did a question about punctuation and regex, but it was confusing.

Supossing I have this text:

```
String text = "wor.d1, :word2. wo,rd3? word4!";
```

I'm doing this:

```
String parts[] = text.split(" ");
```

And I have this:

```
wor.d1, | :word2. | wor,d3? | word4!;
```

**What I need to do to have this?** (Keep the the symbols at the borders, but only that I specify: `.,!?:`, not all).

```
wor,d1 | , | : | word2 | . | wor,d3 | ? | word4 | !
```

---

### UPDATE

I'm getting some good results with these regex, but it's giving an empty char before all splits on punctuation at start of a word.

**There is a way to not have this empty char at the start?**

**Is this regex is good, or there is a more simple way?**

```
public static final String PUNCTUATION_SEPARATOR =
        "("
        + "("
        + "(?=^[\"'!?.,;:(){}\\[\\]]+)"
        + "|"
        + "(?<=^[\"'!?.,;:(){}\\[\\]]+)"
        + ")"
        + "|"
        + "("
        + "(?=[\"'!?.,;:(){}\\[\\]]+($|\n))"
        + "|"
        + "(?<=[\"'!?.,;:(){}\\[\\]]+($|\n))"
        + ")"
        + ")";
```

Comment: See this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static final String PUNCTUATION_SEPARATOR =
    "("
    + "("
    + "(?=^[\"'!?.,;:(){}\\[\\]-]+)"
    + "|"
    + "(?<=^[\"'!?.,;:(){}\\[\\]-]+)"
    + ")"
    + "|"
    + "("
    + "(?=[\"'!?.,;:(){}\\[\\]-]+($|\n))"
    + "|"
    + "(?<=[\"'!?.,;:(){}\\[\\]-]+($|\n))"
    + ")"
    + ")";
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want to use regex ?
There's a faster implementation for splitting by single char: StringTokenizer.
And it that can return the delimiters.

```
String str= "word1, word2. word3? word4!";
String delim = ",.!?";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, delim, true);
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
  String token = st.nextToken();
  ... // token will be: "word1", ",", " word2", ".", etc...
}
```

Comment: This works, but needs to be regex or something more complex, because I only want to spit on the borders (start and end) and not in the middle.

Comment: I mean if the symbol is in the middle of the String (a-b, 20.50), I don't want to splitted, only in the borders (test, [100, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

For simple separators I recommend the StringTokenizer. But here's a solution using regex and another auxiliary separator:

```
String s  = "one,two, three   four ,  five";
s = s.replaceAll("([,\\s]+)", "#$1#");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#");
String[] result = p.split(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex that I think will work:

```
/\s|(?=[\.,:?!](\W|$))|(?<=\W[\.:?!])/
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you want [this](http://www.leghumped.com/blog/2007/12/20/in_array-and-implode-for-java/). First you explode your string and second step you use implode function.