# Splitting string into an array on 16th char

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

I have a text file with various 16 char strings both appended to one another and on separate lines. I've done this

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo("d:\\test.txt");
string FilePath = ("d:\\test.txt");
string FileText = new System.IO.StreamReader(FilePath).ReadToEnd().Replace("\r\n", "");
CharCount = FileText.Length;
```

To remove all of the new lines and create one massively appended string. I need now to split this massive string into an array. I need to split it up on the consecutive 16th char until the end. Can anyone guide me in the right direction? I've taken a look at various methods in String such as `Split` and in `StreamReader` but am confused as to what the best way to go about it would be. I'm sure it's simple but I can't figure it out.

Thank you.

Comment: So you simply want to remove the newline characters?

Comment: @Herblore so each line in the file has 16 chars?

Answer (score 0):

Create a list to hold your tokens. Then get subsequent substrings of length 16 and add them to the list.

```
List<string> tokens = new List<string>();
for(int i=0; i+16<=FileText.Length; i+=16) {
    tokens.Add(FileText.Substring(i,16));
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, this ignores the last token if it has less than 16 characters. If you want it anyway you can write:

```
List<string> tokens = new List<string>();
for(int i=0; i<FileText.Length; i+=16) {
    int len = Math.Min(16, FileText.Length-i));
    tokens.Add(FileText.Substring(i,len);
}
```

Comment: Will fail if string length is not multiple of 16.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov: Thanks for spotting. It should work now.

Comment: I think we shouldn't ignore last part if it has length less than 16. You could use `Math.Min(16, FileText.Length - i)` as length argument.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667927/how-to-keep-the-delimiters-of-regex-split):

You could try something like so:

```
        string longstr = "thisisaverylongstringveryveryveryveryverythisisaverylongstringveryveryveryveryvery";
        IEnumerable<string> splitString = Regex.Split(longstr, "(.{16})").Where(s => s != String.Empty);
        foreach (string str in splitString)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
```

Yields:

```
thisisaverylongs    
tringveryveryver    
yveryverythisisa    
verylongstringve    
ryveryveryveryve
ry
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could look like this (extracted as extension method and made dynamic, in case different token size is needed and no hard-coded dependencies):

```
public static class ProjectExtensions
{
    public static String[] Chunkify(this String input, int chunkSize = 16)
    {
        // result
        var output = new List<String>();
        // temp helper
        var chunk = String.Empty;
        long counter = 0;
        // tokenize to 16 chars
        input.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(ch => 
        {
            counter++;
            chunk += ch;
            if ((counter % chunkSize) == 0)
            {
                output.Add(chunk);
                chunk = String.Empty;
            }
        });
        // add the rest
        output.Add(chunk);

        return output.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The standard usage (16 chars) looks like this:

```
// 3 inputs x 16 characters and 1 x 10 characters
var input = @"1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF1234567890";
foreach (var chunk in input.Chunkify())
{
    Console.WriteLine(chunk);
}
```

The output is:

```
1234567890ABCDEF
1234567890ABCDEF
1234567890ABCDEF
1234567890
```

Usage with different *token size*:

```
foreach (var chunk in input.Chunkify(13))
{
    Console.WriteLine(chunk);
}
```

and the corresponding output:

```
1234567890ABC
DEF1234567890
ABCDEF1234567
890ABCDEF1234
567890
```

It is not a fancy solution (and could propably be optimised for speed), but it works and it is easy to understand and implement.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this method. I haven't tried it , but used it once.

```
    int CharCount = FileText.Length;
    int arrayhold = (CharCount/16)+2;
    int count=0;
    string[] array = new string[arrayhold];
    for(int i=0; i<FileText.Length; i+=16)
       {
          int currentleft = FileText.Length-(16*count);
          if(currentleft>16)
            {
                  array[count]=FileText.Substring(i,16);
            }
          if(currentleft<16)
            {
                  array[count]=FileText.Substring(i,currentleft);
            }

              count++;
        }
```

This is the new code and provide a **TRUE** leftovers handling. Tested in ideone

Hope it works

Comment: -1 Reason is [here](http://ideone.com/dlEwAD) What about remaining characters?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Now it works , proved by [this](http://ideone.com/2gzE7Q)  adding proper way to handle the leftovers. And thanks for ideone.

Comment: @All downvoters , please see this and fix the downvotes , now it works! :( Preferably , upvotes Xb

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
var testArray = "sdfsdfjshdfalkjsdfhalsdkfjhalsdkfjhasldkjfhasldkfjhasdflkjhasdlfkjhasdlfkjhasdlfkjhasldfkjhalsjfdkhklahjsf";
var i = 0;
var query = from s in testArray
            let num = i++
            group s by num / 16 into g
            select new {Value = new string(g.ToArray())};

var result = query.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

result is List containing all the 16 char strings.

Comment: Why the -1? whats wrong with the answer?