# How to split a string and keep the delimiters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, split, translation

I know that you saw many questions like mine, but I hope mine is a little bit different. I'm making a translator and I wanted to split a text into sentences but when I've written this code:

```
public static string[] GetSentences(string Text)
{
    if (Text.Contains(". ") || Text.Contains("? ") || Text.Contains("! "))
        return Text.Split(new string[] { ". ", "? ", "! " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    else
        return new string[0];
}
```

It removed the ".", "?", "!". I want to keep them how can I do it.

---

**NOTE: I want to split by ". " dot and a space, "? " question mark and space...**

Comment: so you want to save the delimiter seperated in the array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep the delimiters of Regex.Split?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667927/how-to-keep-the-delimiters-of-regex-split)

Comment: I want the delimeters to be with a sentence

Comment: Maybe it's higlhy bad, but you can get the lenght of each member in the array after split and then split by legth.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simple, replace them first. I'll use the `"|"` for readability but you may want to use something more exotic.

```
// this part could be made a little smarter and more flexible.    
// So, just the basic idea:
Text = Text.Replace(". ", ". |").Replace("? ", "? |").Replace("! ", "! |");

if (Text.Contains("|")) 
    return Text.Split('|', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

And I wonder about the `else return new string[0];`, that seems odd. Assuming that when there are no delimiters you want the return the input string, you should just remove the `if/else` construct.

Answer (score 2):

Regex way:

```
return Regex.Split(Text, @"(?<=[.?!])\s+");
```

So you just split the string by empty spaces preceded by one of `.`, `?` and `!`.

```
(?<=[.?!])\s+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vS1fI7)**