# How to use Regex to split a string AND include whitespace

Tags: c#, regex, string

I can't seem to find (or write) a simple way of splitting the following sentence into words and assigning a word to the whitespace between the letters.
(VS 2010, C#, .net4.0).

```
String text = "This is a test.";

Desired result: 
[0] = This
[1] = " "
[2] = is
[3] = " "
[4] = a
[5] = " "
[6] = test.
```

The closest I have come is:

```
  string[] words = Regex.Split(text, @"\s");
```

but ofcourse, this drops the whitespace.

Suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

Edit: There may be one or more spaces between the words. I would like all spaces between the words to be returned as a "word" itself (with all spaces being placed in that "word"). e.g., if 5 spaces between a word would be.

String spaceword = "     ";   <--This is not showing correctly, there should be a string of 5 spaces.

Comment: will there be always single whitespace?

Comment: @AmitJoki no. there may be multiple spaces between words. Thanks

Comment: @AlanWayne then what should be the result? do you wanna remove additional spaces?

Comment: Better put it in the question.

Comment: [Relevant answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667927/how-to-keep-the-delimiters-of-regex-split)

Comment: Thanks to Kilazur's link, you can then use `( +)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your pattern to `(\s+)`:

```
        String text = "This        is a   test.";
        string[] words = Regex.Split(text, @"(\s+)");
        for(int i =0; i < words.Length;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + "," + words[i].Length.ToString() + " = " + words[i]);
        }
```

Here's the output:

```
0,4 = This
1,8 =         
2,2 = is
3,1 =  
4,1 = a
5,3 =    
6,5 = test.
```

Comment: I tried earlier, this dropped the white space between words.

Comment: Try my specific example, and take a look at the output in the edit above.  If you are getting different results, please update us with specifics.

Comment: That's it. How did adding the (...) make the difference? Thanks.

Comment: The parenthesis make it a [captured group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), which means it will be kept: "Besides grouping part of a regular expression together, parentheses also create a numbered capturing group. It stores the part of the string matched by the part of the regular expression inside the parentheses."

Comment: It's also [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx) in the MSDN for Regex.Split(): "If capturing parentheses are used in a Regex.Split expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array."

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LINQ` to add spaces manually between them:

```
var parts = text.Split(new[]{ ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var result = parts.SelectMany((x,idx) => idx != parts.Length - 1 
                                         ? new[] { x, " " }
                                         : new[] { x }).ToList();
```

Comment: And the Regex would be?

Comment: The question asks specifically for a Regex, then, however useful, your answer doesn't suit it.

Comment: @Kilazur that's not how it works. That's not how any of SO works.

Comment: @Kilazur As long as the answer solves the OP's problem, you're allowed to post any solution/workarround you think it's better to be used

Comment: @Selman22 Yep. It works!  How could this be done using Regex? Thanks.

Comment: @AlanWayne - Regex isn't always necessary or the best way to do string manipulation. If this works then you don't need a regex

Comment: @ChrisF Very true. Trying to understand regex a  better.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex, `\w+|\s+` which uses or operator `|`

```
var arr = Regex.Matches(text, @"\S+|\s+").Cast<Match>()
                                         .Select(i => i.Value)
                                         .ToArray();
```

It just matches both words and spaces and some LINQ stuff is being used so `arr` is just a `String` `Array`

Comment: so...don't use Regex.Split?

Comment: This is almost perfect.. One problem, the words may contain a "/", i.e., a word could be "w/o". The above regex splits the word on the "/" character. Ideas??