# Extract The Last Part (Section) of a String

Tags: c#, .net, extract, indexof

I need to extract only the last part of a string after a `/` character.

I have tried with `LastIndexOf`, but it fails.

Any solution?

---

#### Attempt

```
var strDiv2 = tbxAff.Substring(tbxAff.IndexOf(" / "), /*value is missing*/ );
dblDiv2 = Convert.ToDouble(strDiv2);`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please edit your question and insert C# code here. However, this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667927/how-to-keep-the-delimiters-of-regex-split will help you.

Comment: Post your code as text, **not** an image. That'll greatly improve your chances of getting an answer. Also, you can get the text from the TextBox so your question is really "*Extract the last part of a string*"

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with TextBoxes, Get the string out of the box and use string functions to manipulate it. Have you tried string.Split?

Comment: LastIndexOf is way to go here, show us your attempt with LastIndexOf

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `String.Split()` function:

```
string[] y = tbxAff.Text.Split(new string[] { " / " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Then use it like this:

```
string strDiv2 = y[1] // Second Part
dblDiv2 = Convert.ToDouble(strDiv2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just omit the second parameter. This would call the [`Substring(int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload, which returns a substring that starts at a specified character position and continues to the end of the string.

```
string strDiv2 = tbxAff.Text.Substring(tbxAff.Text.IndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Also, if you're parsing the extracted substring as a double, you presumably want to exclude the `/` separator character.

Answer (score 0):

string clientSpnd = textBox1.Text.Substring(textBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1);

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension method which will do safety checking:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
     public static string LastPartOfStringFrom(this string str, char delimiter )
     {
         if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)) return string.Empty;

         var index = str.LastIndexOf(delimiter);

         return (index == -1) ? str : str.Substring(index + 1);
     }
}
```