# Regex pattern for splitting a delimited string in curly braces

Tags: c#, arrays, regex

I have the following string

```
{token1;token2;token3@somewhere.com;...;tokenn}
```

I need a `Regex` pattern, that would give a result in array of strings such as

```
token1
token2
token3@somewhere.com
...
...
...
tokenn
```

Would also appreciate a suggestion if can use the same pattern to confirm the format of the string, means string should start and end in curly braces and at least 2 values exist within the anchors.

Comment: What is the regex flavor? What programming language are you using?

Comment: most languages support `split(";")` ?

Comment: I have to use it in C#

Comment: @PavneetSingh please see my comments below the result sample :)

Comment: Good news, in C#, you can do that with regex. Why do you need regex, BTW? You really can use `s.Trim(' ','}','{').Split(';')` and then check if you have 2 or more items in the array. See https://ideone.com/3D23m6

Comment: Thanks, by the way, I would appreciate if there could be a possible regex solution using Regex.Split(string, pattern)

Comment: Ok, so what is the pattern? String start, int number, dot, whitespaces, `{`, `;`-separated items, `}`, end of string?

Comment: I have updated it, please let me know if it is concrete, or should I need to add more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use an anchored regex with named repeated capturing groups:

```
\A{(?<val>[^;]*)(?:;(?<val>[^;]*))+}\z
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CA%7B%28%3F%3Cval%3E%5B%5E%3B%5D*%29%28%3F%3A%3B%28%3F%3Cval%3E%5B%5E%3B%5D*%29%29%2B%7D%5Cz&i=%7Btoken1%3Btoken2%3Btoken3%3B...%3Btokenn%7D)

- `\A` - start of string
- `{` - a `{`
- `(?<val>[^;]*)`  - Group "val" capturing 0+ (due to `*` quantifier, if the value cannot be empty, use `+`) chars other than `;`
- `(?:;(?<val>[^;]*))+` - 1 or more occurrences (thus, requiring at least 2 values inside `{...}`) of the sequence:

  - `;` - a semi-colon
  - `(?<val>[^;]*)`  - Group "val" capturing 0+ chars other than `;`
- `}`  - a literal `}`
- `\z` - end of string.

.NET regex keeps each capture in a CaptureCollection stack, that is why all the values captured into "num" group can be accessed after a match is found.

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/HUVkhx):

```
var s = "{token1;token2;token3;...;tokenn}";
var pat = @"\A{(?<val>[^;]*)(?:;(?<val>[^;]*))+}\z";
var caps = new List<string>();
var result = Regex.Match(s, pat);
if (result.Success)
{
    caps = result.Groups["val"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(t=>t.Value).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I am afraid, this is not working, can you paste the result of the split for {Teddy;Bear;Giant;Gorilla} Lion? Someone deleted the answer where I pasted that example (sorry for that)

Comment: By the way, to ensure at least 2 value, can't we use quantifier like {2,}

Comment: It is working well. You do not need  any limiting quantifiers. I posted the code necessary to obtain the values from the CaptureCollection.

Comment: this is the exception I get using the pattern: Additional information: parsing "\A{(?< val >[^;]*)(?:;(?<val>[^;]*))+}\z" - Invalid group name: Group names must begin with a word character. Ah sorry, wait, my bad, didn't noticed the spaces

Comment: I wan't to use Regex.Match only to confirm the input string format, and Regex.Split to get array straight forward. Is this even possible or am I beating about a bush? ;) If I had to go into explicit looping, then I would have never asked this question

Comment: You do not need to loop. You get all capture values with 1 line using LINQ. As I said, you can both *validate* and *get* all the necessary values with sole regex in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Read it(similar to your problem): [How to keep the delimiters of Regex.Split?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667927/how-to-keep-the-delimiters-of-regex-split).

For your `RegEx` testing use this: http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1.

But `RegEx` is a very resource-intensive, slow operation.

In your case will be better to use the `Split` method of `string` class, for example : `"token1;token2;token3;...;tokenn".Split(';');`. It will return to you a collection of strings, that you want to obtain.

Comment: Splitting won't let *validate* the string.

Comment: Your result example keep all elements of previous collection. How would you like to validate elements of your collection?