# Why is Regex.Split keeping the delimiter when splitting on a regex

Tags: c#, string, split, delimiter

I have the below code splitting a string on a regex:

```
string s = "test;3 régred";
string[] authorsList = Regex.Split(s, "(\\s+)|([\\p{P}\\p{S}])");
foreach (string q in authorsList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(q);
}
```

It's supposed to be splitting and keeping only:

`test`    `3`    `régred`

But it's storing

`test`    `;`    `3`    `*space*`    `régred`

Why is it not losing the delimiters?

Comment: This won't help you, but I suggest that instead of escaping your backslashes with another backslash, you use a literal string, e.g. `@"(\s+)|([\p{P}\p{S}])"`. That way you can shove the RegEx into an online tool like RegExr or Regex101, etc.

Comment: Run it without the capturing groups `()` like  `string[] authorsList = Regex.Split(s, "\\s+|[\\p{P}\\p{S}]");` See https://ideone.com/BczkoU

Comment: @WaiHaLee It's a habit I really need to get out of as it's so much less effort than escaping everything

Comment: @Thefourthbird that did it - perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the delimiters into a capture group by using `(...)`. Remove them and it will work fine:

```
string[] authorsList = Regex.Split(s, @"\s+|[\p{P}\p{S}]");
```

Output:

> test
>   3
>   régred

For reference here is the [inverse question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667927/how-to-keep-the-delimiters-of-regex-split)