# How to split string but keep delimiters in java?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to recreate the way discord parses messages with emoji's inside of it.

For example, I want the message `Hello, :smile::hearth: world!` to split into the following array:

```
["Hello, ", ":smile:", ":hearth:", " world!"]
```

I've already tried to split the array with the following code:

```
Arrays.toString(message.split("(:[A-Za-z]+:)"))
```

However, the split method removes the delimiters found. So the end result looks like this:

```
["Hello", , , " world!"]
```

Comment: Can you try this regex [\s+], split it using space, it will solve.

Comment: @Sambit I want to split it also when not using a space.

Comment: In order for this question to be answerable, you need to include in your question a brief but complete code sample that [reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) you've described in your question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've updated the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As from your input string and expected results, I can infer that you want to split your string basically from three rules.

- Split from the point which is preceded and followed by a colon
- Split from the point which is preceded by a space and followed by a colon
- Split from the point which is preceded by a colon and followed by a space

Hence you can use this regex using alternations for all three cases mentioned above.

```
(?<=:)(?=:)|(?<= )(?=:)|(?<=:)(?= )
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZFe45x/1/)**

Java code,

```
String s = "Hello, :smile::hearth: world!";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("(?<=:)(?=:)|(?<= )(?=:)|(?<=:)(?= )")));
```

Prints like your expected output,

```
[Hello, , :smile:, :hearth:,  world!]
```

Also, as an alternative if you can use matching the text rather than split, the regex would be much simpler to use and it would be this,

```
:[^:]+:|\S+
```

[Regex Demo using match](https://regex101.com/r/ZFe45x/2/)

Java code,

```
String s = "Hello, :smile::hearth: world!";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(":[^:]+:|\\S+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Prints,

```
Hello,
:smile:
:hearth:
world!
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I knew it would be possible but couldn't see the solution. I also didn't know about the Pattern#compile, so another thing learned today! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Please use regular expression's  Lookahead ,Lookbehind to get expected result. Please refer below code snippet to

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
       String message= "Hello, :smile::hearth: world!"; 
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(message.split("(?=,)|(?=(?!)::)|(?<=(:[A-Za-z]+:))")));


    }
```

Which will give output as 
[Hello, , :smile:, :hearth:,  world!]