# Extract BBCode using regex

Tags: regex, bbcode

I'm trying to extract a subset of BBCode (`[U]`,`[B]`,`[I]`) from a string using a regex. I found plenty of questions asking how to simply parse/replace BBCode in a string, but I want to extract all parts - both the normal text parts and the ones enclosed in tags.

I came up with the following regex: `(.*?)(\[[UBI]\](.*?)\[\/[UBI]\])(.*?)`

It seems to almost work, except it misses any "normal text" at the end of the string. For example

`test1 [B]bold text[/B] test2 [U]underlined[/U] test3`

This will result in two matches

```
Match 1:
  group1: test1
  group2: [B]bold text[/B]
  group3: bold text

Match 2:
  group1: test2
  group2: [U]underlined[/U]
  group3: underlined
```

How can I make it match the trailing `test3` as well (either as a new Match or as group4 (which was my intention)?

Comment: That seems to work. Maybe it depends on settings of the environment that you're running it in (which you didn't mention)...

Comment: @MBaas Hmm, where did you try it? I tried it both on [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) and in Dart code, and no matter which modifiers I try I can't get the last part (`test3`) to be included in the matches.

Comment: I tried it in Regexbuddy (sorry, needs download, a Windows app)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `.*?` pattern at the end of the regex pattern. It never consumes any text because *lazy pattern is always skipped first*, the subsequent patterns are tried first. Here, there is nothing after `.*?` and it means it is fine to return a valid match without consuming anything with the last `.*?`.

One possible solution is splitting the string with a regex that keeps captured substrings in the output. Unfortunately, it is not directly supported by Dart, so I enhanced [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59548915/3832970) to account for your case:

```dart
extension RegExpExtension on RegExp {
  List<List<String?>> allMatchesWithSep(String input, int grpnum, bool includematch, [int start = 0]) {
    var result = List<List<String?>>.empty(growable: true);
    for (var match in allMatches(input, start)) {
      var res = List<String?>.empty(growable: true);
      res.add(input.substring(start, match.start));
      if (includematch) {
          res.add(match.group(0));
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < grpnum; i++) {
          res.add(match.group(i+1));
      }
      start = match.end;
      result.add(res);
    }
    result.add([input.substring(start)]);
    return result;
  }
}

extension StringExtension on String {
  List<List<String?>> splitWithDelim(RegExp pattern, int grpnum, bool includematch) =>
      pattern.allMatchesWithSep(this, grpnum, includematch);
}

void main() {
  String text = "test1 [B]bold text[/B] test2 [U]underlined[/U] test3";
  RegExp rx = RegExp(r"\[[UBI]\]([\w\W]*?)\[\/[UBI]\]");
  print(text.splitWithDelim(rx, 1, true));
}
```

Output:

```
[[test1 , [B]bold text[/B], bold text], [ test2 , [U]underlined[/U], underlined], [ test3]]
```

Note the pattern now contains just one capturing group, and this is `grpnum` value (group number). Since you need the whole match in the results, the `includematch` is set to `true`.

The `[\w\W]` will match any chars including line break chars, `.` does not match them by default.