# Split number string on java using regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to using regex on Java to split a number string. 
I using a online regex tester test the regex is right. 
But in Java is wrong.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\\\d]{1,4}");
String[] results = pattern.split("123456");
// I expect 2 results ["1234","56"]
// Actual results is ["123456"]
```

Anything do I missing?

---

I knows this question is boring. But I wanna to solve this problem.
Answer

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\d]{1,4}");
String[] results = pattern.split("123456");
// Results length is 0
System.out.println(results.length);
```

is not working. I have try it. It's will return nothing on the results.
Please try before answer it.

Sincerely thank the people who helped me.

---

Solution:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\d]{1,4})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("123456");
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    results.add(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output 2 results ["1234","56"]

Comment: You are getting an empty array, because split returns the parts *between* the delimiters to split on, throwing away the delimiters themselves. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\\\d]{1,4}")
```

Too many backslashes, try `[\\d]{1,4}` (you only have to escape them once, so the backslash in front of the `d` becomes `\\`. The pattern you wrote is actually `[\\d]{1,4}` (a literal backslash or a literal d, one to four times).

When Java decided to add regular expressions to the standard library, they should have also added a regular expression literal syntax instead of shoe-horning it over Strings (with the unreadable extra escaping and no compile-time syntax checking).

Comment: Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,4}");
String[] results = pattern.split("123456"); The results length is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\d]{1,4})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("123456");
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    results.add(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output 2 results ["1234","56"]

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in one method call, because you can't specify a capturing group for the split, which would be needed to break up into four char chunks.

It's not "elegant", but you must first insert a character to split on, then split:

```
String[] results = "123456".replaceAll("....", "$0,").split(",");
```

Here's the output:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results)); // prints [1234, 56]
```

Note that you don't need to use `Pattern` etc because `String` has a split-by-regex method, leading to a one-line solution.