# How to split Java String but preserve part of its' content?

Tags: java

I am working on java string split. I wish to split the String according to ". uppercase"(There is a space between "`.`" and "uppercase"), for example:

```
". A" ". B" ". C"...
```

Also, I wish to preserve the "." and the "uppercase", is there any efficient way to do that? I use

```
String.split("\\.\\s")
```

before, but it will remove the "." I use. So that's not an ideal solution. Thanks

Sample result

```
String = This is an Egg. This is a dog. "I just come up with this example"
String[0] = This is an Egg.
String[1] = This is a dog. "I just come up with this example"
```

More edit:

There is an issue that the usual way seems will preserve the delimiter at one of it's string. but I wish to split the delimiter in some sense.(in my example, the ". [A-Z]" is splited too)

Comment: It would help if you provided an example String input, and the String[] output tokens you expect.

Comment: the problem is the split function doesn't return the delimiter as part of the strings returned. You can right your own split pretty easily with substring and manually keep the string as you want.

Comment: exact copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
str.split("(?<=\\.\\s+)(?=\p{Lu})")
```

This will split `"First sentence. Foo bar. test"` into the array

```
{ "First sentence. ", 
  "Foo bar. test" }
```

If you don't want the space to be included, just put it between the lookaround assertions:

```
str.split("(?<=\\.)\\s+(?=\p{Lu}")
```

This will result in

```
{ "First sentence.", 
  "Foo bar. test" }
```

For the example string above.

Comment: Hmm...It left the delimiter at the second string, while I wish to save the first part at the first string and the second part at the second string

Comment: @JLTChiu: Edited to use a lookbehind as well as lookahead.

Comment: @JLTChiu: Please check my new edit. I changed `[A-Z]` to `\p{Lu}` for the regex to work with non-ASCII texts.

Answer (score -2):

Here You go:

Use `str.replaceAll(". ",".##");`

`str.replaceAll(".",".##");`

Then use `String.split("##")`

This will give you the required string.

[Check this link](http://www.roseindia.net/java/string-examples/string-replaceall.shtml)

Comment: I didn't downvote this but this is far from what the OP is asking.

Comment: What he is asking is to split the individual lines. i think this method will help him out.

Comment: @VIPIN: No, he was asking to keep the delimited while splitting.

Comment: @VIPIN: Did you downvote me out of revenge or what? That wouldn't be fair at all.

Comment: lol no bud but the solution is not correct according to me and you can check this out

Comment: @VIPIN: Which solution is not correct? I already removed my downvote because you are correct that your solution works to a limited degree. It doesn't fulfil the specification, though. For example, it doesn't work if there is a `##` already in the string or if the whitespace is not followed by an uppercase character or if `\t` or `\n` is used as whitespace.

Comment: any way thanks:) and my goal is to give him a solution so that he can modify it according to his needs:)

Comment: @VIPIN: Do you think OP is too stupid to comprehend lookaround? I doubt that.