# Split the string at numbers and write in the output file in java

Tags: java

I have a text file with string as follows

```
1.dfaf 2.agdagdag 3.dgdfg 4.sdfsasd 5.dfdf 6.gdg7.fadgd8.dsgg9.fgdsf 10.trete
```

I know the logic to read it from file and write to new file

but I want to know the logic to split it at numbers and write in new line in output file

like

```
1.dfaf
2. agdagdag
3. dgdfg
```

etc...

how to get it.

Comment: Homework?  If so, please tag appropriately.  Otherwise never mind.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to write and not store the new string, then you can use do the following. Simply replace the space character with a newline character! The newly created string will thus be in the exact format you want it to be written to the file.

```
  String orignalString = readFromFile(...); // implement this
  String stringToWriteToFile = originalString.replace(" ","\n"); // so you replace the space with a \n
  writeToFile(stringToWriteToFile); // implement this
```

This will work **only** if the strings are consistently separated by a single space.

Note: If this is homework, everybody will use String.split(). So you might get a few extra points for being innovative and using String.replace(). I did myself!

Comment: Maybe it's a typo, but his input string isn't consistent with the space character.

Answer (score 0):

Try String.split
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

You'll need to learn a bit of regular expression to use it, but regex is a very good thing to learn.

Answer (score 0):

[`String.split(Sting regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) would be a great place to start.  Also, regular expressions would be a necessary additional piece to solving your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method to do this:

```
String[] result = "1.dfaf 2.agdagdag 3.dgdfg 4.sdfsasd 5.dfdf 6.gdg7.fadgd8.dsgg9.fgdsf 10.trete".split("\\s");
for (int x = 0; x < result.length; x++) {
    System.out.println(result[x]);
}
```

You can also use a [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to do this, but that seems to be discouraged.

Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the split function and make the delimiter a regex (Space followed by 1 digits)

This should do it...

```
String[] arr = "1.dfaf 2.agdagdag 3.dgdfg 4.sdfsasd 5.dfdf 6.gdg 7.fadgd 8.dsgg 9.fgdsf 10.trete".split(" ");
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may help:

- Once you have the string, finds all the substrings that matches with `\d+\.[a-z]+`. For that you need `java.util.regex.Matcher` and/or `java.util.regex.Pattern`. You can find an example in [Test Harness (The Java™ Tutorials > Essential Classes > Regular Expressions)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html). Look the methods `matcher.find()` and `matcher.group()`.
- Then you have to separate each substring by `.` with `split` if you want to insert a space between number and text.

I hope this can help. Good luck!