# How to divide a sentence contains comma in middle into part Java?

Tags: java, string, text

How can I divide a sentence like `"He and his brother, are playing football."` into few part like `"He"` , `"He and"`, `"and his"`, `"his brother"`, `"brother, "`,`", are"`, `"brother playing"` , `"playing football"`, `"football."` and `"."`. Is it possible to do that by using Java?

```
String[] words = "He and his brother , are playing football .".split("\\s+");
System.out.println(words[0]);
    for (int i = 0, l = words.length; i + 1 < l; i++){
    System.out.println(words[i] + " " + words[i + 1]);  
}
String s = words[words.length-1];       
System.out.println(s.charAt(s.length() - 1));
```

This is the code I have done problem is "," inside the sentence must be separate with the word like `"brother,"` must put as this `"brother ,"` only will work. Any solution?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html See substring(...)

Comment: your split is pretty inconsistent, first you have `"brother, "` where you don't treat comma as a word and then you have `", are" where you do. Although it can be done, you might have to have edge cases for commas and full stops

Comment: That sentence doesn't need a comma :-)

Comment: ya I know, lets assume a sentence contains comma.

Comment: So the only thing wrong with your code is that it gives you `brother ,` instead of `brother,`?

Comment: The String in the sentence is `"He and his brother, are playing football."` then it will not get the result I want. If the string is `"He and his brother , are playing football ."` only will get the result. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
String[] words = "He and his brother , are playing football .".split("\\s+");
```

to:

```
String[] words = "He and his brother , are playing football .".split("[\\s+,]");
```

This will take care of the `,` , that  is, you won't get `brother,`, instead you will only get `brother`. It will split on the occurence of a comma too.

Comment: but the result is not get what I want to. the `,` is missing.

Comment: You probably want to preserve the delimiters. Have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters

Comment: `String[] words = "He and his brother, are playing football.".split("(?!^)\\b");
    System.out.println(words[0]);
  
 for (int i = 0, l = words.length; i + 1 < l; i++){
   System.out.println(words[i] + " " + words[i + 1]);}
 String s = words[words.length-1];  
 System.out.println(s.charAt(s.length() - 1));}`

I cant get the result I want to? any problem with my code