# Spliting a sentence when a hyphen is encountered in java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have following code in my program. It splits a line when a hyphen is encountered and stores each word in the String Array 'tokens'. But I want the hyphen also to be stored in the String Array 'tokens' when it is encountered in a sentence.

```
String[] tokens = line.split("-");
```

The above code splits the sentence but also totally ignores the hyphen in the resulting array.
What can I do to store hyphen also in the resulting array?

Comment: cant you manually add the hyphen? also if suppose you have "abc-xyz"  then you want hyphen with abc like "abc-" or with xyz like "-xyz"

Comment: You don't say where you want the hyphen. As a separate element or attached to a word ?

Comment: i want output like "abc" "-" "xyz"

Comment: Maybe this solution helps you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters

Comment: @SuneetaSingh. What result do you want for : - `"asdf asdf abc - asdf adf"`?

Comment: @RohitJain I want result like: "asdf","asdf","abc","-","asdf","asdf"

Comment: @SuneetaSingh.. Ok, then your question was rather a little confusing. Still I have added a solution for that in my answer too.

Comment: @RohitJain what about "abc- def"? It gives "abc", "-", " def". What can be done to get "abc", "-", "def"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit : -**

Seems like you want to split on both `whitespaces` and `hyphen` but keeping only the `hyphen` in the `array` (As, I infer from your this line - *stores each word in the String Array*), you can use this: -

```
String[] tokens = "abc this is-a hyphen def".split("((?<=-)|(?=-))|\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

Output: -

```
[abc, this, is, -, a, hyphen, def]
```

---

For handling `spaces` before and after hyphen, you can first trim those spaces using `replaceAll` method, and then do split: -

```
"abc this is - a hyphen def".replaceAll("[ ]*-[ ]*", "-")
                            .split("((?<=-)|(?=-))|\\s+");
```

---

**Previous answer : -**

You can use this: -

```
String[] tokens = "abc-efg".split("((?<=-)|(?=-))");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

**OUTPUT : -**

```
[abc, -, efg]
```

It splits on an `empty` character before and after the `hyphen (-)`.

Comment: And if there are no empty chars?

Comment: This doesn't split space-separated words though, does it ?

Comment: @Romczyk.?? There is always one.

Comment: @BrianAgnew.. It will, but it will include the space in the previous and next word.

Comment: @BrianAgnew.. For e.g for `"abc - efg"` it will give: - `[abc , -,  efg]`. Note the space after `abc` and `efg`.

Comment: "abc this is-a hyphen def".split("((?<=-)|(?=-))") gives me a three-element array as a result

Comment: @BrianAgnew.. Well, OP is splitting on just `hiephen`, I assumed.

Comment: @BrianAgnew.. To also split on space, you can add a `space` in split criteria also: - `"((?<=-)|(?=-))|\\s+"`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a regular expression in combination with the Java Pattern and Matcher. Example:

```
String line = "a-b-c-d-e-f-";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^-]+|-");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
while (m.find())
{
  String match = m.group();
  System.out.println("match:" + match);
}
```

To test your regular expression you could use an online regexp tester like [this](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)