# Splitting up a string by what matches and does not match the regex

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, arraylist

I am currently have a program that can find all the regexs that are in a string, however for a different part I want the parts that match the regex and the parts that don't.

So if I had `<h1> hello world </h1>` I would want to be able to split it up into [`<h1>`, `hello world`, `</h1>`].

Does anyone have any ideas on how to they would go about this?

Here is my code that splits up the string to find the regex part

```
ArrayList<String> foundTags = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<(.*?)>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(HTMLLine);
while(m.find()){
    foundTags.add(m.group(0));
}
```

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1154145

Comment: @nattyddubbs Yeah normally I would agree with you except that I already have a function that can successfully tell if its html or just text. I am looking to find a way to split of the string by everytime I find a regex that matches the criteria listed above. where "<h1> hello world </h1>" = [ h1, hello world, /h1]. The logic of how to tell if its html is already written and tested in another part of the code

Comment: Valid html: `<h1><>`. I'm just saying text processing on Html isn't that reliable. Continue at your own risk...

Comment: @leonbloy I thought of that but I was not sure how to write that with the regex as the splitter

Comment: @nattyddubbs I would agree with you but the problem that I am trying to solve will be giving me HTML in a text format and I need to figure out how to parse though it correctly. Once I find either text or a HTML tag I am creating it into an object that will make it easier to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters):

```
String text = "testing<hi>bye</hi><b>bla bla!";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<(.*?)>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
int last_match = 0;
List<String> splitted=new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
        splitted.add(text.substring(last_match,m.start()));
        splitted.add(m.group());
        last_match = m.end();
    }
    splitted.add(text.substring(last_match));
System.out.println(splitted.toString());
```

prints `[testing, <hi>, bye, </hi>, , <b>, bla bla!]`

Is that what you want? You can easily fix the code to omit empty elements if you don't want them:

```
while (m.find()) {
    if(last_match != m.start())
        splitted.add(text.substring(last_match,m.start()));
    splitted.add(m.group());
    last_match = m.end();
}
if(last_match != text.length())
    splitted.add(text.substring(last_match));
```

Bear in mind, as pointed out in the comments: using regex to parse arbitrary HTML/XML is in general a bad idea.

Comment: yeah, I know its not the best way to parse HTML but its the required way and if I am given an invalid tag I have a method to check each tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex grouping ability to retrieve the different parts of the match. For example:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(<.*?>)(.*)(<.*?>)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("<h1> Hello World </h1>");
while(m.find()){
    list.add(m.group(1));
    list.add(m.group(2));
    list.add(m.group(3));
}
```

Would give you the list you wanted: `["<h1>", " Hello World ", "</h1>"]`. Note that group number 0 is the full matched expression.

Comment: Is there a way to find the number of groups?

Comment: I believe the number of groups depends on how many groups you make. In the regex, parens separate groups, so in the expression above, `(<.*?>)(.*)(<.*?>)`, there are 3 sets of parens so 3 groups (4 if you count the whole expression).