# java string split into array, how to save into the same array the char im splitting with?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

for example: `strEquation="36+5-8X2/2.5"`

My code is :

```
String[] tmp = strEquation.split("[X\\+\\-\\/]+");

for(int i=0; i<tmp.length; i++)
    Log.d("Split array",tmp[i]);
```

and my output as i thought it would be :

```
36
5
8
2
2.5
```

I want the `tmp` string array will put also the char I'm splitting with, like this:

```
tmp[0] = 36
tmp[1] = +
tmp[2] = 5
tmp[3] = -
tmp[4] = 8
tmp[5] = X
tmp[6] = 2
tmp[7] = /
tmp[8] = 2.5
```

Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: check these links
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters


and


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters

Comment: Just a comment. For all that complex regex you have within your double quotes, you could've just had a "//D",

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about splitting before or after each of `X` `+` `-` `/` characters? BTW you don't have to escape `+` and `/` in character class (`[...]`)

```
String[] tmp = strEquation.split("(?=[X+\\-/])|(?<=[X+\\-/])");
```

seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you're trying to get all the matches and not to split the string so

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[X+/-]|[^X+/-]+").matcher(strEquation);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

but the answer above is more clever :)

Also: you don't need to escape `+` and `/` chars inside of square braces; minus (`-`) sign need to be escaped only if it's not first or last character on the list