# Python: How can I include the delimiter(s) in a string split?

Tags: python, string, parsing, split

I would like to split a string, with multiple delimiters, but keep the delimiters in the resulting list. I think this is a useful thing to do an an initial step of parsing any kind of formula, and I suspect there is a nice Python solution.

Someone asked a similar question in Java [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters).

For example, a typical split looks like this:

```
>>> s='(twoplusthree)plusfour'
>>> s.split(f, 'plus')
['(two', 'three)', 'four']
```

But I'm looking for a nice way to add the plus  back in (or retain it):

```
['(two', 'plus', 'three)', 'plus', 'four']
```

Ultimately I'd like to do this for each operator and bracket, so if there's a way to get

```
['(', 'two', 'plus', 'three', ')', 'plus', 'four']
```

all in one go, then all the better.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do that with Python's `re` module.

```
import re
s='(twoplusthree)plusfour'
list(filter(None, re.split(r"(plus|[()])", s)))
```

You can leave out the list if you only need an iterator.

Answer (score 4):

```
import re
s = '(twoplusthree)plusfour'
l = re.split(r"(plus|\(|\))", s)
a = [x for x in l if x != '']
print a
```

output:

```
['(', 'two', 'plus', 'three', ')', 'plus', 'four']
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an easy way using `re.split`:

```
import re

s = '(twoplusthree)plusfour'
re.split('(plus)',  s)
```

**Output:**

```
['(two', 'plus', 'three)', 'plus', 'four']
```

`re.split` is very similar to `string.split` except that instead of a literal delimiter you pass a regex pattern. The trick here is to put () around the pattern so it gets extracted as a group.

Bear in mind that you'll have empty strings if there are two consecutive occurrencies of the delimiter pattern

Answer (score 0):

this thread is old, but since its top google result i thought of adding this:

if you dont want to use regex there is a simpler way to do it. basically just call split, but put back the separator except on the last token

```
def split_keep_deli(string_to_split, deli):
    result_list = []
    tokens = string_to_split.split(deli)
    for i in xrange(len(tokens) - 1):
        result_list.append(tokens[i] + deli)
    result_list.append(tokens[len(tokens)-1])
    return  result_list
```

Answer (score 0):

## Here i'm spliting a string on first occurance of alpha characters:

```
def split_on_first_alpha(i):
    #i="3.5 This is one of the way"
    split_1=re.split(r'[a-z]',i,maxsplit=1, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    find_starting=re.findall(r'[a-z]',i,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    split_1[1]=find_starting[0]+split_1[1]
    return split_1
```