# Split concatenated functions keeping the delimiters

Tags: python, regex, string, split, python-re

I am trying to split strings containing python functions, so that the resulting output keeps separate functions as list elements.
`s='hello()there()'` should be split into `['hello()', 'there()']`
To do so I use a regex lookahead to split on the closing parenthesis, but not at the end of the string.

While the lookahead seems to work, I cannot keep the `)` in the resulting strings as suggested in various posts. Simply splitting with the regex discards the separator:

```
import re
s='hello()there()'
t=re.split("\)(?!$)", s)
```

This results in: `'hello(', 'there()']` .

```
s='hello()there()'
t=re.split("(\))(?!$)", s)
```

[Wrapping the separator as a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators) results in the `)` being retained as a separate element: `['hello(', ')', 'there()']`
As does [this approach using the `filter()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208223/python-how-can-i-include-the-delimiters-in-a-string-split):

```
s='hello()there()'
u = list(filter(None, re.split("(\))(?!$)", s)))
```

resulting again in the parenthesis as a separate element: `['hello(', ')', 'there()']`

How can I split such a string so that the functions remain intact in the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**`re.findall()`**](https://www.guru99.com/python-regular-expressions-complete-tutorial.html#7)

1. `\w+\(\)` matches one or more word characters followed by an opening and a closing parenthesis> That part matches the `hello()` and `there()`

```py
t = re.findall(r"\w+\(\)", s)
```

---

```
['hello()', 'there()']
```

***Edition:***
`.*?` is a non-greedy match, meaning it will match as few characters as possible in the parenthesis.

```
s = "hello(x, ...)there(6L)now()"

t = re.findall(r"\w+\(.*?\)", s)       
print(t)
```

---

```
['hello(x, ...)', 'there(6L)', 'now()']
```

Comment: alright, that does it. can you quickly elaborate on the regex you used and how it differs from my attempts?

Comment: Does the part after `|` serve any purpose here?

Comment: `re.findall(r"\w+\(\)")` would do, too. No need to check for the end of the string here.

Comment: You are right @fsimonjetz

Comment: thank you. could this be extended to also work for other formats including arguments? such as `"hello(x, ...)there(6L)now()"` for example

Comment: And how do you expect the output to look like? @ORené

Comment: I would hope for it to be `"['hello(x, ...), 'there(6L)', 'now()']"`, where the functions were again split into separate elements, on `)`, retaining the closing paranthesis

Comment: @ORené Are keyword arguments supported? Also, are arbitrary spaces allowed between a comma and the next argument?

Comment: @Fractalism Yes exactly. I would hope for this to work for `"hello(data=x, capitalize = True)there()my(x = x)friend(x, 6L, ...)"` as well ideally

Comment: I found a better approach so edited the answer one more time. @ORené

Comment: it even works for this extended example: `re.findall(r"\w+\(.*?\)", y)` thank you so much @JamiuS., it is perfect

Answer (score 2):

You can split on a lookbehind for `()` and negative lookahead for the end of the string.

```py
t = re.split(r'(?<=\(\))(?!$)', s)
```