# Splitting java string into pattern wise parts.

Tags: java, regex, string

I have to splitt a string , keeping in mind that split should at the pattern change spot.

```
String nxy= "xI  yam yw  1a 2pro xgr  xon xsig  yk  yn ya 2h 3h xpr xoc yes ysin  yn" 
String[] patterns=nxy.split(    regex=???????     );
```

String has three types of words.
    1. starting with number : 1a, 2h etc.
    2. starting with x: xl, xgr, xon etc.
    3. starting with y: yam, yn, ye etc.

I need to split it in three types of parts:

```
1. contains words starting with number
2. contains words starting with x
3. contains words starting with y
```

in other words string 'nxy' is to be divided into following parts:

```
xI 
yam yw  
1a 2pro 
xgr  xon xsig  
yk  yn ya 
2h 3h 
xpr xoc 
yes ysin  yn
```

I need help for:

```
String[] patterns=nxy.split(    ????????????????      );
```

Comment: Does it have to be a regex?

Comment: So `yam yw` is one group after splitting, or would it be `yam, yw`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String temp = nxy.replaceAll("(?:\\b(x|y)[^\\s]*(?:(?:\\s+\\1[^\\s]*)*))|(?:(?:\\s+\\d[^\\s]*)+)","$0\n");
    for (String o : temp.split("\\n")) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone wrote a class just for this special case.

Give it a try: [Is there a way to split strings with String.split() and include the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275768/is-there-a-way-to-split-strings-with-string-split-and-include-the-delimiters)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea where to begin to do that with regex, but I wrote a couple methods that should handle your case.

```
public List<String> splitByCrazyPattern(String nxy) {
    String[] split = nxy.split(" ");
    List<String> patterns = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = 0; i < split.length(); i++) {
        String string = split[i];
        while(checkNext(string.substring(0, 1)), string[i+1]) {
            i++;
            string += " " + split[i];
        }
        patterns.add(string);
    }
    return patterns;
}

public boolean checkFirst(String first, String string) {
    if (first.equals(string.substring(0,1))) {
        return true;
    }
    if (first.matches("[0-9]") && string.substring(0, 1).matches("[0-9") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

String nxy= "xI  yam yw  1a 2pro xgr  xon xsig  yk  yn ya 2h 3h xpr xoc yes ysin  yn";
String[] patterns= splitByCrazyPattern(nxy);
```

Haven't tested, but I'm pretty sure it should work. Hope it helps!